# dpkg error: "trying to overwrite file, which is also in..."

Tags: apt, software-installation, dpkg

For example:

```
$ sudo apt-get install curl
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
bsh : Depends: libjline-java but it is not going to be installed
groovy : Depends: libjline-java but it is not going to be installed
rhino : Depends: libjline-java but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. 

Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I get the same or similar errors when I attempt to install clojure1.3, leiningen, and several other packages.

When I try the suggestion made in the error message, this is what happens:

```
$ sudo apt-get -f install 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  diffstat linux-headers-3.2.0-26-generic linux-headers-3.2.0-26 dh-apparmor dkms html2text libmail-sendmail-perl libsys-hostname-long-perl
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libjline-java
Suggested packages:
  libjline-java-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libjline-java
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
23 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/72.0 kB of archives.
After this operation, 129 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
(Reading database ... 226243 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking libjline-java (from .../libjline-java_1.0-1_all.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/libjline-java_1.0-1_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/java/jline.jar', which is also in package scala 2.9.2-400
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libjline-java_1.0-1_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 bsh : Depends: libjline-java but it is not installed
 groovy : Depends: libjline-java but it is not installed
 rhino : Depends: libjline-java but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

Comment: Also looks live you need to install java, search for it in software center

Comment: Probably a duplicate of [this Q&A](http://askubuntu.com/questions/25761/broken-package-error-after-updating) or at least the [solution](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/02/fix-dpkg-error-trying-to-overwrite-x.html) should help

Comment: @markkirby, I have run `sudo apt-get update` if that is what you are asking.

Comment: The solution by @Lety here is the most appropriate and least invasive approach, if you are working on your own installers - https://askubuntu.com/questions/491401/how-do-i-install-a-so-file-newbie

Answer (score 165, accepted):

Please don't go for the [danjjl answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/176132/169736) directly, if you face this kind of "trying to overwrite" error, is likely that you have conflicting packages that need to be solved first.

The immediate fix for the issue is to remove the conflicting package that is undesirable, in this case `scala`,

```
sudo dpkg -P scala
```

Next it would be recommended to submit a bug report with the respective package maintainers. This normally imply adding a `Conflict: package` line in the control file.

Also see [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/430443/202806) answer for more detailed explanation about this error.

Comment: Not so sure about this advice.  I think it depends on the situation.  In the link to your earlier posting, there is a conflict from two versions of the same software.  I agree there that one should remove the older software first.  However, if there is a problem with how two different programs were packaged and the file that is being overwritten is identical or otherwise harmless, then I don't see a problem with the advice.  No, not ideal...but it's probably a bit extreme to ask someone to not go for the a particular answer if the alternative is to wait until the problem is bug fixed...

Comment: @Ray in that case a bug report may be in order... but I doubt software from Ubuntu repositories has that problem, since they pull from Debian and Debian tests for these kind of problems exhaustively.

Comment: @Braiam It's been a long time since I used Debian.  Perhaps it's better now, but I saw similar problems with Debian.  It isn't because of lack of exhaustive testing, but sometimes it is hard to test every possible scenario.  No matter how much testing is performed, something can slip through.  I'm not against writing a bug report, but "easier said that done".  After all, it may be hard to summarize all of the conflicting packages.  And, if bugs are not "hot" (i.e., they don't affect a lot of people), you'll just end up waiting.

Comment: Perhaps it would be better if the original answer was modified so that it said, "Please don't do because of (some reason)."  So that someone can choose to ignore it once they know the pros and cons.  As it stand, the answer above just says don't do it.

Comment: @Ray umm... when building a package dpkg stores a list of files (dpkg -L package) and simply looking for collisions should be enough for first measure. And by exhaustive testing I meant real world testing, unstable and testing are there precisely for this kind of stuff

Comment: @Ray you really don't want two versions of the same package. You don't. It only gives more problems in the long run, this answer makes sure you understand that and its advise is to be taken *seriously*, not "ignored"

Comment: About conflicts -- I don't know how dpkg works.  You got me there.  But I've seen it a few times (i.e., very rarely...once a year or two?) to think that things do get missed.  As for your second point, I agree with you that it's not good to have two version of the same package.  I just think that the original statement to not follow someone else's advice is a bit heavy-handed.  There is a time and place for --force-overwrite and explaining it by offering the pros/cons seems more helpful than saying don't follow someone's advice that works.

Comment: And just to clarify, I noticed that you edited the answer recently.  So, I don't know what it said 8 months ago when I first wrote my comment.  If you're editing the answer and improving it, then great!  But as you do, of course, what I'm saying is becoming less and less relevant.

Comment: In my case, I used checkinstall to create a custom version of GTK3, which in debian is split into several packages. As I wasn't sure how many packages libgtk3 was split into, I made a single package for all of it. This package will be replaced automatically when libgtk-3-0 gets updated, so I had a valid use case for this.

Comment: FYI *This* solution worked for me. Offending package in my case was `libc6-dev-i386`

Comment: I'm getting nvidia-418 conflicting with nvidia-390. How am I supposed to upgrade drivers then?

Comment: uninstall all the nvidi* drivers first and then install 418 version.

Comment: After hours of wrestling, THIS worked for me. Offending package: libkf5akonadi-data. Thanks

Comment: it seems to work for me, I did `sudo dpkg -P libaudqt2` which is the old package, and after that `sudo apt --fix-broken install` worked (previously it didn't work).

Comment: This rescued me with some Qt dev packages

Comment: In my case the conflict was between `mono-devel` and `discodos`. I uninstalled `discodos`. Works for me.

Comment: I added a warning to that dangerous answer. It's in the edit queue, so if anyone with more rep could approve my edit, that would be nice. Most of my StackExchange rep is on StackOverflow so I can't do direct edits here.

Comment: Worked for 
```
npacking libpython3.7-stdlib:amd64 (3.7.13-1+focal3) over (3.7.13-1+focal1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libpython3.7-stdlib_3.7.13-1+focal3_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/__init__.py', which is also in package python3.7-distutils 3.7.13-1+focal1
```
by running `sudo dpkg -P python3.7-distutils`

Thanks a lot and have a great weekend :D

Answer (score 179):

#### **Warning: This answer is dangerous and may lead to a broken system (because this will effectively install the package but new problems may arise when both the packages try to use the same library/file/binary). Use [Avinash Raj's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/433510/149519) instead. Also consider reporting a bug for *both* conflicting packages.**

---

You have to force overwrite the files causing issues:

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite <file-path>
```

In your case it would be:

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/libjline-java_1.0-1_all.deb
```

Check that everything is fixed by running:

```
sudo apt-get --fix-broken install
```

If you still have problems, rerun the first step with any of the `dpkg: error processing (...)` remaining.

*Solution found on [webupd8](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/02/fix-dpkg-error-trying-to-overwrite-x.html)*

Comment: This will effectively install the package but the problem remains when both package tries to use the same library/file/binary.

Comment: Goodness, no, that's a recipe for a broken system...

Comment: "force-overwrite" probably should at least have some kind of warning/disclaimer

Comment: awesome, this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Could you provide more information of `--force-overwrite`? Doesn't seems to be present [on current `dpkg`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/dpkg.1.html)

Comment: THIS ANSWER IS DANGEROUS! Use Avinash Raj's answer instead, and then file a bug report with BOTH package maintainers. In my case the conflict was between `mono-devel` and `discodos`. I uninstalled `discodos`.

Comment: The conflicting file could just be a `man` page (what I'm not sure of, is if apt only reports the _first_ conflicting file or reports all of them, i.e. maybe it exits with error because of a `man` page, your run it again with `--force-overwrite` and then in overwrites some important binary files)

Comment: This did help me after a messy upgrade to Ubuntu 22.04. But yeah, dangerous stuff. Have a boot USB ready when doing this.

Comment: Oh you saved my nerves man. Python-numpy was driving my nuts. I even deleted everything related to it and still had no success. Thanx.

Comment: I used this command when the conflicting file was a background JPG file. I thought that couldn't lead to the biggest problems.

Comment: This was the only thing that worked for me when a direct package upgrade (no second package involved, probably just a buggy script) failed on debian testing. Thank you so much.

Comment: This seems to have worked for me since I was switching from Wayland to non-Wayland and wanted to get Espanso working again: `sudo apt install ./espanso-debian-x11-amd64.deb -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-overwrite"`

Answer (score 88):

@danjjl's command works for `.deb` files. I found this command works with `apt`/`apt-get`:

```
sudo apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-overwrite" install <package-name>
```

Comment: Great tipp. Be careful though: Overwriting things can cause serious trouble if the files are different. One of your conflicting packages will no longer function properly.

Comment: `sudo apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-overwrite" install -f` worked for me for a similar issue

Comment: @Cat: More like "great hack" then. ;-]

Comment: Adding `-o Dpkg::Options::="--force-overwrite" ` to my apt command fixed my problem! Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Not sure that is a global fix as I had the same issue, but with a libglx-mesa file in the cache conflicting with Nvidia-390.  I removed the file and issued an `apt install -f -y`, let that finished and then proceeded with the `apt update`, `upgrade` and `autoremove` in that sequence.

I got the error while executing an `apt dist-upgrade` on Ubuntu 18.04 and continued the process again, no more issues and that seemed to be "my" fix.

Commands:

```
sudo su -
mv /var/cache/apt/archives/libglx-mesa0_18.0.0~rc5-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb ~
apt install -f -y
apt update -y
apt upgrade -y
apt autoremove -y
apt dist-upgrade
```

PS: Forcing an overwrite was a bad idea that I tried and I got lucky.  But it's better to find the root cause, and fix it.  I still have to investigate but the error lead me to move the file out the way.

Answer (score 3):

So `dpkg --force-overwrite` is the hacky workaround that has been presented here in various forms. But [`dpkg-divert`(8)](https://linux.die.net/man/8/dpkg-divert) is the intended way to handle this situation.

Answer (score 3):

For Debian, Ubuntu, etc., let `aptitude` handle it for you`:

```bash
sudo apt update
sudo apt install aptitude

sudo aptitude install my_package_name
# Then choose the necessary options. Ex: for me I choose No, Yes, Yes,
# to choose to downgrade the troublesome package. Then it installs and
# works!
```