# Glitch while installing or updating software?

Tags: 12.10

[image][image]Anytime I install something or update Ubuntu, I notice this during the ending process in the terminal:

```
linux-image-3.5.0-23-generic
linux-image-extra-3.5.0-23-generic
linux-image-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1).
```

Is there a fix for this?

Comment: Check the logs to find what is causing it. `gedit /var/log/dpkg.log`

Comment: This is the problem I believe I'm having when I used the command and text editor shows the issue I'm having:     status half-configured linux-image-3.5.0-23-generic:amd64 3.5.0-23.35

Comment: `dpkg -C` will tell you what all is not configured correctly.
You can try `dpkg --configure linux-image-3.5.0-23-generic` to try to finish the configuration.

Comment: I tried the commands and they did't work. I took a screenshot of it on terminal. How would I paste the photo on this page?

Comment: Edit your question with an image block.

Comment: That helps alot!

Answer (score 0):

Purging those kernel packages and their configuration files, then re-installing them may solve the issue. In terminal:

`sudo apt-get purge linux-image-3.5.0-23-generic linux-image-extra-3.5.0-23-generic linux-image-generic && sudo apt-get install linux-image-3.5.0-23-generic linux-image-extra-3.5.0-23-generic linux-image-generic`

Comment: Still No change. Now I get a red alert icon in the taskbar in the upper right corner of my screen. If I can't find a solution, I'm going back to 12.04.I uploaded a photo above to show the results of my attempt.

Comment: @MichaelScott try running `sudo apt-get -f install` or `sudo dpkg --configure --pending` ([source](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/debian-26/sub-process-usr-bin-dpkg-returned-an-error-code-1-a-171107/#post3753885))

Comment: Also, I would suggest checking out [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/195950/package-system-broken-e-sub-process-usr-bin-dpkg-returned-an-error-code-1).

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem on a VirtualBox and the problem was I didn't have PAE enabled.