# how to resolve unmet dependencies and file collisions due mixing diferent repositories?

Tags: apt

Apt-get is broken for unresolved dependencies. I follow other answers and I do:`sudo apt-get -f install`
I get

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  account-plugin-generic-oauth appmenu-qt5 dbconfig-common gnome-control-center-unity hud indicator-bluetooth libaio1 libavcodec53 libavformat53 libavutil51 libbamf3-1 libcdr-0.0-0
  libclucene-contribs1 libclucene-core1 libcmis-0.3-3 libcolorhug1 libcolumbus0-0 libcolumbus0-0-common libdbusmenu-qt5 libdc1394-22 libdvdnav4 libdvdread4 libexttextcat-2.0-0 libgexiv2-2
  libgsm1 libhaml-ruby1.8 liblangtag-common liblangtag1 libmemcached6 libmspub-0.0-0 libnux-4.0-0 libnux-4.0-common libopencv-core2.4 libopencv-highgui2.4 libopencv-imgproc2.4 libqt5core5
  libqt5dbus5 libqt5gui5 libqt5widgets5 libschroedinger-1.0-0 libsqlite0 libswscale2 libtbb2 libva1 libvisio-0.0-0 libxcb-icccm4 libxcb-image0 libxcb-keysyms1 libxcb-randr0 libxcb-render-util0
  libxcb-sync0 linux-headers-3.8.0-23 linux-headers-3.8.0-23-generic linux-image-3.8.0-23-generic linux-image-extra-3.8.0-23-generic python-central python-kaa-base python-kaa-metadata
  python-oneconf python-sqlite python-support python-xlib ruby-haml systemd-shim
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  linux-image-extra-3.8.0-35-generic
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-image-extra-3.8.0-35-generic
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 30.7 MB of archives.
After this operation, 96.1 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-security/main linux-image-extra-3.8.0-35-generic i386 3.8.0-35.50 [30.7 MB]
Fetched 30.7 MB in 44s (686 kB/s)                                                                                                                                                                 
(Reading database ... 395476 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking linux-image-extra-3.8.0-35-generic (from .../linux-image-extra-3.8.0-35-generic_3.8.0-35.50_i386.deb) ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-extra-3.8.0-35-generic_3.8.0-35.50_i386.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/lib/modules/3.8.0-35-generic/kernel/arch/x86/platform/iris/iris.ko', which is also in package linux-image-3.8.0-35-generic 3.8.0-35.52~precise1
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 3.8.0-35-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.8.0-35-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 3.8.0-35-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.8.0-35-generic
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-extra-3.8.0-35-generic_3.8.0-35.50_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

relevant info
`uname -r
3.8.0-35-generic`

cat /etc/apt/sources.list

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 12.10 _Quantal Quetzal_ - Release i386 (20121017.2)]/ quantal main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring main restricted
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring-security multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring-security multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu quantal partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu quantal partner

## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring main
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring main
```

cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*

```
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/bjori/php5/ubuntu raring main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/bjori/php5/ubuntu raring main
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/bjori/php5/ubuntu raring main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/bjori/php5/ubuntu raring main
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/caffeine-developers/ppa/ubuntu raring main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/caffeine-developers/ppa/ubuntu raring main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/caffeine-developers/ppa/ubuntu raring main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/caffeine-developers/ppa/ubuntu raring main
### THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY CONFIGURED ###
# You may comment out this entry, but any other modifications may be lost.
deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
### THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY CONFIGURED ###
# You may comment out this entry, but any other modifications may be lost.
deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
### THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY CONFIGURED ###
# You may comment out this entry, but any other modifications may be lost.
deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
# needed sources for php5.3:
deb http://kambing.ui.ac.id/ubuntu/ precise main restricted
deb-src http://kambing.ui.ac.id/ubuntu/ precise main restricted

deb http://kambing.ui.ac.id/ubuntu/ precise-updates main restricted
deb-src http://kambing.ui.ac.id/ubuntu/ precise-updates main restricted

deb http://kambing.ui.ac.id/ubuntu/ precise universe
deb-src http://kambing.ui.ac.id/ubuntu/ precise universe
deb http://kambing.ui.ac.id/ubuntu/ precise-updates universe
deb-src http://kambing.ui.ac.id/ubuntu/ precise-updates universe

deb http://kambing.ui.ac.id/ubuntu/ precise multiverse
deb-src http://kambing.ui.ac.id/ubuntu/ precise multiverse
deb http://kambing.ui.ac.id/ubuntu/ precise-updates multiverse
deb-src http://kambing.ui.ac.id/ubuntu/ precise-updates multiverse
deb-src http://kambing.ui.ac.id/ubuntu/ natty-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security multiverse

deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu natty partner

deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main

deb http://kambing.ui.ac.id/ubuntu/ precise-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://kambing.ui.ac.id/ubuntu/ precise-backports main restricted universe multiverse


deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner


# needed sources for php5.3:
deb http://kambing.ui.ac.id/ubuntu/ precise main restricted
deb-src http://kambing.ui.ac.id/ubuntu/ precise main restricted

deb http://kambing.ui.ac.id/ubuntu/ precise-updates main restricted
deb-src http://kambing.ui.ac.id/ubuntu/ precise-updates main restricted

deb http://kambing.ui.ac.id/ubuntu/ precise universe
deb-src http://kambing.ui.ac.id/ubuntu/ precise universe
deb http://kambing.ui.ac.id/ubuntu/ precise-updates universe
deb-src http://kambing.ui.ac.id/ubuntu/ precise-updates universe

deb http://kambing.ui.ac.id/ubuntu/ precise multiverse
deb-src http://kambing.ui.ac.id/ubuntu/ precise multiverse
deb http://kambing.ui.ac.id/ubuntu/ precise-updates multiverse
deb-src http://kambing.ui.ac.id/ubuntu/ precise-updates multiverse
deb-src http://kambing.ui.ac.id/ubuntu/ natty-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security multiverse

deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu natty partner

deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main

deb http://kambing.ui.ac.id/ubuntu/ precise-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://kambing.ui.ac.id/ubuntu/ precise-backports main restricted universe multiverse


deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner


# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu raring main # disabled on upgrade to raring
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu raring main # disabled on upgrade to raring
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu quantal main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu quantal main
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu raring main # disabled on upgrade to raring
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu raring main # disabled on upgrade to raring
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/sublime-text-3/ubuntu raring main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/sublime-text-3/ubuntu raring main
# deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/sublime-text-3/ubuntu raring main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/sublime-text-3/ubuntu raring main
```

sudo dpkg --configure -a

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-generic:
 linux-image-generic depends on linux-image-extra-3.8.0-35-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-extra-3.8.0-35-generic is not installed.

dpkg: error processing linux-image-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-generic:
 linux-generic depends on linux-image-generic (= 3.8.0.35.53); however:
  Package linux-image-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing linux-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-generic-pae:
 linux-generic-pae depends on linux-generic (= 3.8.0.35.53); however:
  Package linux-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing linux-generic-pae (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-generic
 linux-generic
 linux-generic-pae
```

Edit: I found that my sources.list have been messed up mainly due to the use of 
https://gist.github.com/awm086/6510924 to downgrade a version of php

Comment: I have seen it and it did not help...

Comment: what when you tried to follow the answer?

Comment: @Ali There are quite a few answers on that questions. Did you only try the first one?

Comment: Have you seen this? http://askubuntu.com/questions/195950/package-system-broken-e-sub-process-usr-bin-dpkg-returned-an-error-code-1

Comment: @Alvar I have followed the answere until i reached a deadend. I get to the point of `sudo apt-get -f install` and it errors out. Now, I am at the `Getting help` section.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have dependencies issues but simply file collisions due mixing diferent repositories `precise`, `quantal` and `raring`. I'm not even sure what your system is anymore, which you should check using `lsb_release -sc` or use `quantal` as the header of the `sources.list` file suggest. You should remove/comment all the repositories that are not your version of Ubuntu, update your package list (`sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get update`) and pray that `sudo apt-get -f install` doesn't throw more errors. Ah, you should also remove the `linux-image-extra-3.8.0-35-generic` package.

Comment: also it is raring. `lsb_release -sc` gives  `raring`

Comment: @Ali I would give up that installation, and for the next time not mixing repositories as you did.

Comment: Thanks, I am not sure how repositories were mixed. Also, every time I do `sudo apt-get -f install` i get `The following extra packages will be installed:  linux-image-extra-3.8.0-35-generic`. Lastly, what do you mean by give up the installation? Start over?

Comment: Thank you, I fixed it. This started when I tried a specific type of php installation for phpbrew that gave me some dependencies problem when I executed `apt-get build-dep php5`.I tried to resolve them following other answers and made the problem worse. This along with possible existing problems on my system(mixed repos)led to the mess. I followed you advice and used quantal. In etc/apt/ I noticed sources.list.distUpgrade. so I did `sudo cp sources.list.distUpgrade sources.list` then `sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get update` and then `sudo apt-get upgrade` and everything is working fine now.