# WSL Ubuntu cuda installation messed up

Tags: dpkg

I am getting an error while trying to install sklearn:

```
Reading package lists... Done  
Building dependency tree  
Reading state information... Done

You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.

The following packages have unmet dependencies:

 cuda-drivers : Depends: nvidia-418 (>= 418.40.04) but it is not going to be installed

 libcuda1-418 : Depends: nvidia-418 (>= 418.40.04) but it is not going to be installed

 nvidia-418-dev : Depends: nvidia-418 (>= 418.40.04) but it is not going to be installed

 nvidia-opencl-icd-418 : Depends: nvidia-418 (>= 418.40.04) but it is not going to be installed

 python-sklearn : Depends: python-numpy but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: python-scipy but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: python-sklearn-lib (>= 0.19.1-3) but it is not going to be installed

                  Depends: python-joblib (>= 0.9.2) but it is not going to be installed

                  Recommends: python-nose but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: python-pytest but it is not going to be installed
                  Recommends: python-matplotlib but it is not going to be installed

E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I tried `sudo apt --fix-broken install` but I get:

```
Unpacking nvidia-418 (418.40.04-0ubuntu1) ...

dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/nvidia-418_418.40.04-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb (--unpack):

 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX_indirect.so.0', which is also in package libglx-mesa0:amd64 18.2.2-0ubu ntu1~18.04.2

Errors were encountered while processing:

 /var/cache/apt/archives/nvidia-418_418.40.04-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb

E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Also tried purging either nvidia-418 or the packages dependent on it using `sudo apt-get remove --purge getdeb-repository` to no avail. How do I deal with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the apt prevent you from `--fix`ing because you had package that being used by two different package, hence the 'trying to overwrite' message. This answer by [@AvinashRaj](https://askubuntu.com/users/202806/avinash-raj) explain what trigger the error.

> From the above error report it was clearly shown that, while running `sudo apt-get install -f` command `dpkg` tries to extract and install
>   **`.deb` file 1**. Installation requires to place **`package_file_A`** on the
>   `/usr/bin` directory.
>
> But it was shocked on seeing the same **`package_file_A`**
>   file on the `/usr/bin` directory and produced the error, because this
>   file was placed to `/usr/bin` during the installation of **`some_package`**.

<sub>I changed several word, all credits goes to https://askubuntu.com/a/430443/253251</sub>

### What to do ?

For a dirty hack you can try to force overwrite the offending files, be careful though.

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/nvidia-418_418.40.04-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

You can then attempt to fix remaining problem.

```
sudo apt -f install
```