# Broken package manager

Tags: apt, package-management

[Broken package manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JcVKS.png)

[Trying to fix problem with sudo apt-get install -f](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QoNJw.png)

Question: how to delete all unmet dependencies? I'm just rage now and hate apt. >.<

UPD: output of `sudo apt install -f`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libvdpau1:i386
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libvdpau1:i386
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 13 not upgraded.
218 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/24,4 kB of archives.
After this operation, 116 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
(Reading database ... 203285 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libvdpau1_1.3-1ubuntu2_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libvdpau1:i386 (1.3-1ubuntu2) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libvdpau1_1.3-1ubuntu2_i386.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite shared '/etc/vdpau_wrapper.cfg', which is different from other instances of package libvdpau1:i386
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libvdpau1_1.3-1ubuntu2_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Please replace images of text with copy/pasted text. Read your output: Your problem seems clearly explained in the `install -f` output. That happens when you unwisely add non-Ubuntu sources that provide incompatible packages. This would be much easier to lead you through if we could copy/paste and highlight the important bits of your output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sudo dpkg -P {defect package}` helps to solve this problem.
For more info about this problem read here:
[trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/opencv_haartraining', which is also in package libopencv2.3-bin 2.3.1+svn6514+branch23-12~oneiric](https://askubuntu.com/questions/195950/trying-to-overwrite-usr-bin-opencv-haartraining-which-is-also-in-package-lib/430443#430443)