# Ubuntu SDK does not install on Ubuntu 12.04 64bit?

Tags: apt, software-installation, dependencies, ubuntu-touch, android

Trying to install the ubuntu-sdk on Ubuntu 12.04 64bit using instructions at http://developer.ubuntu.com/get-started/gomobile/ and I get the following errors:

> Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
>   requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
>   distribution that some required packages have not yet been created or
>   been moved out of Incoming. The following information may help to
>   resolve the situation:
>
> The following packages have unmet dependencies:  ubuntu-sdk : Depends:
>   ubuntu-qtcreator-qt5libs but it is not going to be installed
>                 Depends: ubuntu-qtcreator-plugins but it is not going to be installed E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken
>   packages.

it appears that android-tools-adb is missing.  I am able to get this installed but when trying to install ubuntu-sdk I am told that there is a an error (conflict with qt4 and qt5) and that qtchooser will not install.

> E:
>   /var/cache/apt/archives/qtchooser_0.0.1~git20121229.g8f08405-0ubuntu1~precise1~test5_amd64.deb:
>   trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/qdbusxml2cpp', which is also in package
>   libqt4-dev

I hear some people saying that the sdk can only be installed on Ubuntu 12.10....is this still the case?  I really want to write apps.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/363200/e-unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages) and [dpkg error: “trying to overwrite file, which is also in…”](https://askubuntu.com/questions/176121/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [dpkg error: "trying to overwrite file, which is also in..."](https://askubuntu.com/questions/176121/dpkg-error-trying-to-overwrite-file-which-is-also-in)

Answer (score 2):

You can install it on 12.04 as well. The workaround is to manually install the package:

```
sudo dpkg --force all -i /var/cache/apt/archives/qtchooser_0.0.1~git20121229.g8f08405-0ubuntu1~precise1~test5_amd64.deb 
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo dpkg --force all -i /var/cache/apt/archives/qtchooser_0.0.1~git20121229.g8f08405-0ubuntu1~precise1~test5_amd64.deb 
sudo apt-get -f install
```

I had a dpkg error on 12.04 that stopped on qtchooser also.

Installing the package from the archive didn't work as shown but it worked after I copied the file from the /var/cache/apt/archives to my home directory and did the sudo dpkg --force all -i from there.

Also the name of my qtchooser package was slightly different but it was easy to get because it was displayed in the original error message.