# Firefox installation error in Kubuntu 12.10

Tags: installation, 12.10, firefox, kubuntu

I keep getting this error:

```
Package: /var/cache/apt/archives/firefox_20.0+build1-0ubuntu0.12.10.3_amd64.deb
Error: trying to overwrite '/usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop', which is also in package kubuntu-firefox-installer 12.04ubuntu1
```

I am only trying to install Firefox as a browser. Interestingly, it will not let me remove the "Firefox Installer" either. Any suggestions?

Comment: How are you installing Firefox?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [dpkg error: "trying to overwrite file, which is also in..."](https://askubuntu.com/questions/176121/dpkg-error-trying-to-overwrite-file-which-is-also-in)

Answer (score 0):

Thus is an issue with the Kubuntu Firefox installer. The easiest way to fix this is to use Muon package manager to remove the package called `kubuntu-firefox-installer`.

Then you should be able to install Firefox without a problem. If it still doesn't work, use Muon to install the package `firefox-globalmenu`.

That took care of my problems.

Answer (score 0):

DWcoder is correct just remove the kubuntu-firefox-installer package, but when you install firefox, firefox-globalmenu is a depend of firefox so it will be installed anyway.

Answer (score -1):

It worked.

Removing Firefox Installer. In Terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install kubuntu-firefox-installer
```

Then type your sudo (your user password) password to install Firefox and Chromium.