# Rhythmbox updates failing

Tags: apt, dpkg, rhythmbox

I am having trouble updating with Rhythmbox.  I'm using ubuntu 13.10

I have purged it and did a new install and I keep getting an error message:

[image: Imgur]

When I attempt an upgrade:

```
vividvibe@vividvibe-P55M-UD2:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
  librhythmbox-core7
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 812 kB of archives.
After this operation, 39.9 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
Get:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jacob/media/ubuntu/ saucy/main librhythmbox-core7 amd64 3.0.1-0~13.10~ppa1 [812 kB]
Fetched 812 kB in 1s (578 kB/s)              
(Reading database ... 259190 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace librhythmbox-core7 2.99.1-0ubuntu1 (using .../librhythmbox-core7_3.0.1-0~13.10~ppa1_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement librhythmbox-core7 ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/librhythmbox-core7_3.0.1-0~13.10~ppa1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/librhythmbox-core.so.8.0.0', which is also in package librhythmbox-core8 3.0.1-1ubuntu5~ppa0
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/librhythmbox-core7_3.0.1-0~13.10~ppa1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Not sure what the problem could be.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [dpkg error: "trying to overwrite file, which is also in..."](https://askubuntu.com/questions/176121/dpkg-error-trying-to-overwrite-file-which-is-also-in)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open your terminal and paste as

```
 sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/librhythmbox-core7_3.0.1-0~13.10~ppa1_amd64.deb
```

hope thats going to help you.