# "dpkg: trying to overwrite '.../gsettings/gnome-settings-daemon.convert also in package gnome-settings-daemon" when upgrading to Trusty

Tags: dpkg, gnome-settings-daemon

While upgrading to 14.04 I ran into a dependency issue `gnome-settings-daemon-schemas` which blocked the upgrade. After running `sudo apt-get -f install` I get:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  gnome-settings-daemon-schemas
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  gnome-settings-daemon-schemas
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 530 not upgraded.
9 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/44.2 kB of archives.
After this operation, 189 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 252639 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../gnome-settings-daemon-schemas_3.8.6.1-0ubuntu11_all.deb ...
Unpacking gnome-settings-daemon-schemas (3.8.6.1-0ubuntu11) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/gnome-settings-daemon-schemas_3.8.6.1-0ubuntu11_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/GConf/gsettings/gnome-settings-daemon.convert', which is also in package gnome-settings-daemon 3.10.2-0ubuntu1~saucy6

Processing triggers for gconf2 (3.2.6-0ubuntu2) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/gnome-settings-daemon-schemas_3.8.6.1-0ubuntu11_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
   Depends: gnome-settings-daemon-schemas (< 3.10) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

What has caused this and how do I progress to fix it?

---

In case it's relevant, here's the original dependency hell:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 aptitude : Depends: aptitude-common (= 0.6.8.2-1ubuntu4) but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libboost-iostreams1.54.0 but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libcwidget3 but it is not going to be installed
            Depends: libept1.4.12 but it is not going to be installed
 compiz-gnome : Depends: gnome-settings-daemon-schemas (>= 3.4.2-0ubuntu9) but it is not going to be installed
 unity-settings-daemon : Depends: gnome-settings-daemon-schemas (>= 3.8) but it is not going to be installed
                         Depends: gnome-settings-daemon-schemas (< 3.10) but it is not going to be installed
```

Comment: related bug report https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/1286404

Comment: This question does not require any further editing other than by the OP to respond to additional queries.  Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [dpkg error: "trying to overwrite file, which is also in..."](http://askubuntu.com/questions/176121/dpkg-error-trying-to-overwrite-file-which-is-also-in)

Answer (score 3):

First of all, I tried to edit your question and make from it a canonical question for the following error:

```
Unpacking package_name ...
    dpkg: error processing archive /path/to/archive_name.deb (--unpack):
     trying to overwrite 'file_name', which is also in package another_package_name
```

My answer will be for this general case, but also for your particular case:

1. You can solve your problem by running:

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /path/to/archive_name.deb
   ```

   - In your particular case:

     ```
     sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/gnome-settings-daemon-schemas_3.8.6.1-0ubuntu11_all.deb
     ```
2. If somehow the first step doesn't work, run also:

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i --force-all /path/to/archive_name.deb
   ```

   - In your particular case:

     ```
     sudo dpkg -i --force-all /var/cache/apt/archives/gnome-settings-daemon-schemas_3.8.6.1-0ubuntu11_all.deb
     ```
3. Finally, run again:

   ```
   sudo apt-get -f install
   ```

   - If you have the same problem with another package, start again with first step.

[Source](http://ubuntuinromania.blogspot.com/2014/03/eroare-la-instalareactualiazare-dpkg.html)

Comment: meta and chat are for discussing edits ;)

Comment: I'm sad that you use this method for all your problems. Following your advice OP will have a mixure of 3.10 gnome packages meant for saucy and some packages 3.6/3.8 meant for trusty.

Comment: @Braiam Don't be. If you think that's the case, what's the problem? Better to overwrite them than remove them... If there are more packages with the same problem, `apt-get -f install` will complain about them.

Answer (score 2):

This error is produced because before the installation you **didn't removed/purged the gnome ppa** along with the packages. This is evident since those package gnome-settings-daemon 3.10.2-0ubuntu1~saucy6 is not present in saucy repositories, but in gnome PPA's.

You can try removing one by one using dpkg all those packages ending in saucy:

```
sudo dpkg --remove package
```

remove all the PPA repositories and use `aptitude remove '?version(*saucy*)'` (if you have synaptic, that's another option) if you have it installed, downgrade it, or reinstall your system.

Comment: -1 because this is not the way how a user should interact with Ubuntu: to remove all the PPA repositories when upgrading (which is your main point in the answer).

Comment: @RaduRădeanu ["Before upgrading your system to a new Ubuntu release (i.e. from Ubuntu 13.04 to 13.10), **you should probably run ppa-purge ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3 first.](https://launchpad.net/~gnome3-team/+archive/gnome3)**" Before upgrading your system, you should remove PPA's that will be in the way

Comment: @Braiam You very likely have the exact cause of the issue here but the fix is a bit lacklustre. I'm not sure what stage the upgrade is at but could the user retroactively ppa-purge the old versions (or delete all orphaned gnome packages?). Picking through packages manually is likely going to leave a system full of mixed 3.10 and 3.08 versions. *Edit* Just saw the last line... Maybe work that into the answer more?

Comment: @Oli actually no, if OP removes all the packages ending in saucy, [which is appended](https://launchpad.net/~gnome3-team/+archive/gnome3?field.series_filter=saucy) for them all, through for a moment he wouldn't have desktop at all but at the end the packages will fit in place

Comment: @Braiam *...probably...* (not sure). And removing gnome PPA can have no effects, because it was probably already automatically disabled through the `do-release-upgrade` command (the OP already uses 14.04 - see [1st revision](http://askubuntu.com/revisions/451254/1)).

Comment: @RaduRădeanu come on. It's a fact that it cause problems otherwise OP wouldn't ask this question, don't you think?

Answer (score 1):

This issue happened to me recently as well. Not only had to remove the Gnome repository I manually added to stay on the bleeding edge, but also purge all the Gnome packages that could have gotten in the way (i.e. came from that repository) and then, after `apt-get update` installed `gnome-shell` version from the *Trusty* repos, which of course, brought in all its dependencies, including `gnome-settings-daemon-schemas`. Hope, your mileage won't vary too much.

Answer (score 0):

Try running this command

```
sudo aptitude install gnome-settings-daemon
```

ref : https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/1278863/comments/16