# unable to securely remove '/usr/bin/gsettings.dpkg-new': Permission denied

Tags: 18.04, apt

When I run `apt-get upgrade` using root user, I got...

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libglib2.0-dev : Depends: libglib2.0-bin (= 2.56.4-0ubuntu0.18.04.4) but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

When I try `apt --fix-broken install` as it prompted, I got...

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libglib2.0-bin
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libglib2.0-bin
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 17 not upgraded.
9 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/68.7 kB of archives.
After this operation, 284 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 91896 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libglib2.0-bin_2.56.4-0ubuntu0.18.04.4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libglib2.0-bin (2.56.4-0ubuntu0.18.04.4) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libglib2.0-bin_2.56.4-0ubuntu0.18.04.4_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 unable to securely remove '/usr/bin/gsettings.dpkg-new': Permission denied
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libglib2.0-bin_2.56.4-0ubuntu0.18.04.4_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Basically, is there any way I can install that `libglib2.0-bin`?

---

Edit:

I tried `sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/libglib2.0-bin_2.56.4-0ubuntu0.18.04.4_amd64.deb`

and I got...

```
(Reading database ... 91896 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libglib2.0-bin_2.56.4-0ubuntu0.18.04.4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libglib2.0-bin (2.56.4-0ubuntu0.18.04.4) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libglib2.0-bin_2.56.4-0ubuntu0.18.04.4_amd64.deb (--install):
 unable to securely remove '/usr/bin/gsettings.dpkg-new': Permission denied
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libglib2.0-bin_2.56.4-0ubuntu0.18.04.4_amd64.deb
```

So what does `unable to securely remove '/usr/bin/gsettings.dpkg-new': Permission denied` mean?
I tried to manually `rm` this file and it appeared again immediately.

---

Edit:

`ls -al /usr/bin/gsettings.dpkg-new` returns:

`-rwxrwxrwx 0 root root 26696 Jul  4  2019 /usr/bin/gsettings.dpkg-new`

and

`lsattr /usr/bin/gsettings.dpkg-new` returns:

`lsattr: Inappropriate ioctl for device While reading flags on /usr/bin/gsettings.dpkg-new`

Comment: `ls -al /usr/bin/gsettings.dpkg-new`please and `lsattr /usr/bin/gsettings.dpkg-new`

Comment: @nobody Thank you for your advice! Question updated.

Comment: Do you run the apt-get commands with sudo ? They needs elevated rights to work.

Comment: @SorenA The whole thing happens in root user with root privilege.

Comment: Turn your system off. Boot a live-linux and make filesystemcheck. Look during the repair for errors.  And I think it is also recommend to check your harddrive with smartmontools. And of course make a backup from yout datas.

Answer (score 1):

I finally managed to delete everything depending on `libglib2.0-dev` and install everything again and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Look like a problem with the archive. Try removing it by doing the following:

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/libglib2.0-bin_2.56.4-0ubuntu0.18.04.4_amd64.deb
```

This question looks a lot like [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/451254/dpkg-trying-to-overwrite-gsettings-gnome-settings-daemon-convert-also-in) and it was already explained in more detail

Comment: This command returns similar thing(shown in question). I am reading the question given and see whether something might work.