# How do I install a .so file? - newbie

Tags: software-installation, tar, shared-library, audacity

I downloaded freeverb.tar.gz which contains a plugin library (freeverb.so) for Audacity.

I extracted the .tar.gz file to my downloads folder but I don't know what to do next. There is no 
Readme file or any other info contained in the .tar.gz file, just freeverb.so

Can you advise me how to get the freeverb.so installed into the correct folder for Audacity to pick it up?

Answer (score 8):

According to [ubuntu manual](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/maverick/man8/ldconfig.8.html):

> **ldconfig**  creates,  updates,  and removes the necessary links and
> cache (for use by the run-time linker,  ld.so)  to  the  most  recent
> shared libraries  found  in  the directories specified on the command
> line, in the file /etc/ld.so.conf, and in the trusted directories
> (/usr/lib  and /lib).

So, assuming that `freeverb.so` is located in `/home/yourUser/Download` directory (folder), create folder in your home:

```
mkdir /home/yourUser/myLibrary
```

and copy `freeVerb.so` library:

```
cp /home/yourUser/Download/freeverb.so /home/yourUser/myLibrary
```

create a simple file `freeverb.conf` like this:

```
echo "/home/yourUser/myLibrary" > freeverb.conf
```

Add you configuration file `freeverb.conf` in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d` directory (in this directory you can find files as example)

```
sudo cp freeverb.conf /etc/ld.so.conf.d
```

Run `ldconfig` in order to configure dynamic linker run-time bindings.

```
sudo ldconfig
```

If `/etc/ld.so.conf.d` doesn't exists, you can add your path at the end of `/etc/ld.so.conf` file.

At the end, if all went well, you can remove unnecessary file:

```
rm freeverb.conf
rm /home/yourUser/Download/freeverb.so
```

Comment: Hi Letizia thank you for answering my question. This is how far I have got - I created freeverb.conf file in text editor containing the path to my freeverb.so file but when I try to save it to /etc/ld.so.conf.d directory I get error message 'Do not have permission to save to  /etc/ld.so.conf.d directory' when I use UI. Could you tell me please what is the sudo command I need to use in the command line to add this file? I know this is basic but I have only come over from Windows and this is all new to me, many thanks, Dave

Comment: I updated the answer

Comment: Hi Letizia,dt@laptop:~$ sudo cp freeverb.conf /etc/ld.so.conf.d
[sudo] password for dt: 
cp: cannot stat `freeverb.conf': No such file or directory

Comment: I updated the answer

Comment: Hi Letizia, removed unnecessary freeverb.so file, I now somehow have a locked freeverb.so directory within my Home directory, I tried to remove it with -r /home/user/freeverb.so but I get error message '-r : command not found  I also tried -R and --r

Comment: Pay attention with `rm` command, try `ls -l /home/user/freeverb.so` in order to verify file permission and if file exists. If it belongs to your user, it could be read-only (-r--r--r--), in this case use `rm -f /home/user/freeverb.so`. I think you forgot Download folder in path, isn't it?

Comment: Hi, Letizia, ls -l /home/user/freeverb.so command returned  total 0. I checked freeverb.so directory's permissions via GUI and they are root ownership . I no longer have freeverb.so file in Downloads, only freeverb.so directory in /home/user/

Comment: I'm a little bit confused. Did you follow the step I described in the answer? If you did, and the only step you missed is the last "remove unnecessary file", then you should have `freeverb.so` in `/home/yourUser/myLibrary`. In this case you can remove it with: `sudo rm /home/user/freeverb.so`

Comment: Hi Letizia, you are correct, I missed an important step, now rectified, and resolved, Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The simple approach is to put the file in `/usr/local/lib`, `chown` the file to `root:root`, and `chmod` it to `755`.

However, managing system files manually is not something I would personally recommend, so if possible I would search for a prebuilt `.deb` file for your particular version of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

You can install the package containing the library in a clean system (such as reference docker container with the same system) and then copy the missing shared library (as reported during failed run attempts) from the installed location (such as `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/`) to exactly the same location in the target system or container.

Be warned that multiple additional packages may need to be installed to extract all the necessary dependencies (a common problem with so-called "distroless" containers). It is therefore best to list all dependencies using `ldd` to avoid an iterative process.