# libmysqlclient error. No file (even though its there)

Tags: mysql

Trying to launch a program. I get the error as follows:

```
./theforgottenserver: error while loading shared libraries: libmysqlclient.so.16: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I have libmysqlclient.so.15 in the /usr/lib64 directory. So the file is there, i even put it in the programs directory that I am trying to launch.

Comment: Could you modify your question with the command you run? I guess you forgot to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

Comment: the command i am running is just ./theforgottenserver   its a program for a game.

Answer (score 0):

According to Ubuntu manual:

> ldconfig creates, updates, and removes the necessary links and cache
>   (for use by the run-time linker, ld.so) to the most recent shared
>   libraries found in the directories specified on the command line, in
>   the file /etc/ld.so.conf, and in the trusted directories (/usr/lib and
>   /lib).

In your case, verify if `/usr/lib64` is present in `/etc/ld.so.conf`, and if it is, exec:

```
  sudo ldconfig
```

If `/usr/lib64` is not present in `ld.so.conf`, you can follow [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/491401/how-do-i-install-a-so-file-newbie/491428#491428) as example on how to add your custom directory and update link loader.