# Error when installing clipgrab on Trusty

Tags: apt, software-installation, ffmpeg

I wanted to install clipgrab on Trusty, but get the following error when running `sudo apt-get install clipgrab` (I added the PPA and ran `apt-get update`):

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  clipgrab
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 351 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/203 kB of archives.
After this operation, 713 kB of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 247242 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../clipgrab_3.4.2~trusty3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking clipgrab (3.4.2~trusty3) ...
dpkg: error processing archive     /var/cache/apt/archives/clipgrab_3.4.2~trusty3_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/ffmpeg', which is also in package ffmpeg 7:2.3-1~trusty
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.54ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/clipgrab_3.4.2~trusty3_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

As far as I can understand, the installation process has a problem with ffmpeg already existing. How can I fix this?

Comment: This sounds like bad packaging, and no fault on your part. I would contact the maintainer and notify him/her of this, and to either add `ffmpeg` as a Conflicts or rename or not include the `ffmpeg` binary.

Comment: @saiarcot895 any reason why you commented instead of answering? Just curious.

Comment: @kraxor: I guess I'm just used to commenting. Changed to an answer.

Comment: @saiarcot895 this is like a reverse of the "not an answer" flag :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [dpkg error: "trying to overwrite file, which is also in..."](https://askubuntu.com/questions/176121/dpkg-error-trying-to-overwrite-file-which-is-also-in)

Answer (score 2):

This looks like bad packaging on the part of the PPA maintainer, and no fault on your part. I would contact the maintainer and notify him/her of this, and to either:

- add ffmpeg as a Conflicts,
- rename this binary, or
- not include this binary (if it is the same as the one in `ffmpeg`).