# "trying to overwrite '/usr/share/man/man1/node.1.gz', which is also in package nodejs-legacy 0.10.25~dfsg2-2ubuntu1"

Tags: software-installation, dpkg

I am trying to install nodejs but it is repeatedly failing. Attached is the log

```
$ sudo apt-get install nodejs
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libc-ares2 libv8-3.14.5
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  rlwrap
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  rlwrap
The following packages will be upgraded:
  nodejs
1 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 11 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/4,391 kB of archives.
After this operation, 14.9 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Selecting previously unselected package rlwrap.
(Reading database ... 263979 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../rlwrap_0.37-5_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking rlwrap (0.37-5) ...
Selecting previously unselected package nodejs.
Preparing to unpack .../nodejs_0.10.31-1chl1~trusty1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nodejs (0.10.31-1chl1~trusty1) over (0.10.25~dfsg2-2ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/nodejs_0.10.31-1chl1~trusty1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/man/man1/node.1.gz', which is also in package nodejs-legacy 0.10.25~dfsg2-2ubuntu1
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/nodejs_0.10.31-1chl1~trusty1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: can you run `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade`?

Comment: @CharlesGreen I could get it working. I have self answered my question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [dpkg error: "trying to overwrite file, which is also in..."](http://askubuntu.com/questions/176121/dpkg-error-trying-to-overwrite-file-which-is-also-in)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One thing which i had missed was to purge the previous installation and reinstall. 
I used the following command to remove the previous install

```
sudo apt-get purge nodejs-legacy nodejs
```

and

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

to reinstall nodejs.

[Linking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25094718/error-on-update-alternatives-when-installing-upgrading-nodejs-v0-10-30) the SO answer which helped me

Comment: Ah, you figured it out before I finished typing! :) I'd still recommend looking into NVM, though, so you can avoid doing `sudo npm install` every time you want to install modules with npm.

Answer (score 10):

### Potentially Fixing the Installation

As Charles said in the comments, I would try to run `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade`.  You may also want to run `sudo apt-get autoremove` to remove packages that you no longer need.

The error mentions the `nodejs-legacy` package.  If you've ever installed that, you may want to remove it.

### A better way to install Node on Ubuntu

Unless you are planning on using your computer as a production server, I'd strongly recommend installing Node.js using the [NVM tool](https://github.com/creationix/nvm).  Installing from the repository requires you to use `sudo`, which leads to [messy permissions when you try to install Node modules](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16151018/388639) using NPM.

As a bonus, NVM lets you install multiple versions of Node, and it lets you keep your copy of Node up-to-date, even if the official repositories are behind.

Grab the latest copy of NVM

```
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.15.0/install.sh | bash
```

Tell your shell to use `nvm`

```
source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
```

Then install a node version

```
nvm install 0.10
```

And tell nvm which version of Node you want to use

```
nvm use 0.10
```

Comment: Thank you for this. Telling me about nvm really helped me out. I was getting so sick of fighting with permissions.

Comment: You can also resolve permissions issues by updating your prefix path in ~/.npmrc so you are pointing at your home dir.