# How to install NodeJS 4 using apt?

Tags: apt, software-installation, nodejs

How can I install [NodeJS 4](https://nodejs.org/en/) on Ubuntu using `apt-get` utilities?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Instructions were taken from here: https://github.com/nodesource/distributions

```
wget -qO- https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_4.x | sudo bash -
```

and then:

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

Here is the system versions:

```
ubuntu@424c7702-0947-e7c7-c532-dfec484fc109:~$ lsb_release -r
Release:    15.04
ubuntu@424c7702-0947-e7c7-c532-dfec484fc109:~$ node -v
v4.0.0
ubuntu@424c7702-0947-e7c7-c532-dfec484fc109:~$ npm -v
2.14.2
```

Comment: @jarserver - "The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nodejs : Depends: rlwrap but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages."- Error while apt-get install. How to fix this?

Comment: @KumarSambhav sounds like your package database is in a broken state search the site for how to fix apt broken state.

Comment: This doesn't work for me on ubuntu 15.10
It always installs v0.10.25 (lower version than the OP, so I have no idea what's going on...)

Comment: @HankScorpio It sounds like the apt-repo was not updated. Try following the manual installation instruction (https://github.com/nodesource/distributions#manual-installation) and see if that fixes it.

Comment: Yes, that's what the problem was. Some GPG keys (whatever they are) were missing, so `apt-get update` was failing every time. I used `y-ppa-manager` to fix the problem and now I have the latest version of NodeJS 4.

Comment: https://www.seancassidy.me/dont-pipe-to-your-shell.html - Friends don't let friends pipe to sh

Comment: We really should not be encouraging wget | sudo bash. Downvoted.

Answer (score 37):

#### Node Version Manager always has the latest

I'm strongly of the opinion that [installing Node with Node Version Manager](https://askubuntu.com/a/519715/2079) is the best option on Ubuntu, if you're installing it on a computer where you intend to do development (instead of a production server).

When you install through the official repositories, you end up with something terribly outdated. You can always add a PPA, but you'll still end up with [messy permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16151018/388639) where globally installing modules from npm requires admin privileges.

With NVM, everything is kept in your home folder (so no need for `sudo`), and you can install multiple versions of Node (including 4.0) and switch between them with ease.

#### Installation with NVM

Taken from the [NVM installation instructions](https://github.com/creationix/nvm#installation):

Grab the latest copy of NVM (you may need to `sudo apt-get install curl` first):

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.26.1/install.sh | bash
```

Tell your shell to use `nvm` (you may want to add this to `~/.bashrc` so it happens automatically in the future):

```
source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh
```

Then install the latest node version:

```
nvm install 4.0
```

And tell nvm which version of Node you want to use:

```
nvm use 4.0
```

You may also want to add the `nvm use 4.0` line to your `~/.bashrc`, so that you don't have to pick a node version each time you start your terminal.

Now if you check `which node` it should give you a path to the node executable inside your home folder. Running `node --version` should tell you you're running `v4.0.0`.

Comment: I don't think the messy permissions comment is accurate, I install node from nodesource apt repo and can run and install node modules in my local home directory (including -g global option). All it takes is updating ~/.npmrc to define your prefix directory.

Comment: Ah, that's a very fair point. I'm still a fan of nvm for the version management aspect, but if that's not your thing, setting a prefix in `~/.npmrc` definitely seems to be the right way to handle permissions for global modules.

Comment: I believe the "outdated" note about the official repositories, in the answer is a bit ... outdated ;-) The official repositories now support any publicly released version on a supported release train - there're repos for version 6, 7 and even 8, and has been like that since at least my answer below (10/15)

Answer (score 35):

With kudus to @jarsever, I personally don't subscribe to the "[curl|sh](http://curlpipesh.tumblr.com/)" paradigm.

If you feel the same kind of unease as I do when asked to just pipe some arbitrary text off the internet and into a root account's shell process, then you may want to try this for the same effect but with (slightly) less fear, uncertainty and doubt:

```
version=4
apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv 68576280
apt-add-repository 'deb https://deb.nodesource.com/node_${version}.x precise main'
apt-get update
apt-get install nodejs
```

I believe the process should be clear, and you can also do the same through Ubuntu's Software Properties UI.

Comment: Is there any disadvantage to doing it this way? Seems like the best option...

Comment: It's more than one line, and allows you to learn about your system?... Some people don't like that, I think, that's the only way I can explain the `curl|sh` phenomenon.

Comment: In addition to getting to learning about about your OS's package manager, it's also a security issue. `curl|sh` pulls a script from a server, and executes it directly in a shell. I personally trust nodesource, but it's not a great habit to get into. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/46286/read-and-confirm-shell-script-before-piping-from-curl-to-sh-curl-s-url-sh

Comment: And there asking you to pipe it into `sudo -E bash`. It's running as root. I highly recommend you read, and understand the script, if you're going to pipe it from the net into a root shell.

Comment: Generally speaking, by installing a deb package you take the same amount of risk as piping the internet into a root shell. That being said, one implies you understand your system, the other implies that you don't - and that is a huge difference.

Comment: This answer is at least more reliable and secure, as it follows a chain of trust.

Answer (score 0):

I like to use nodeenv from pypi (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/nodeenv), you install the package using pip, then setup a "node/virtualenv" and tell it to install a prebuilt version, fast and simple.
Paul

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me

```
echo 'export PATH=$HOME/local/bin:$PATH' >> ~/.bashrc
. ~/.bashrc
mkdir ~/local
mkdir ~/node-latest-install
cd ~/node-latest-install
curl http://nodejs.org/dist/node-latest.tar.gz | tar xz --strip-components=1
./configure --prefix=~/local
make install 
curl https://www.npmjs.org/install.sh | sh
```

Source: https://gist.github.com/isaacs/579814

Comment: The question is specifically about how to install NodeJS with *Apt*.