# Why can't I install git and node.js?

Tags: 14.04, git, nodejs

I installed Ubuntu alongside Windows.
I know I have git and node on Windows, but I can't open them on Ubuntu, and I also can't install them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install NodeJS 4 using apt?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/672994/how-to-install-nodejs-4-using-apt)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We’re sorry, but Ask Ubuntu is not a forum, but a Question & Answer site: it works best if you ask one question, so you can receive one answer. When you ask multiple questions, you need to find one expert versed in multiple areas, which becomes unlikelier the more questions you put into, well, one question! ;-) So please, split up your question into multiple questions and drop me a comment so I can answer one of your questions.

Answer (score 3):

What is showing when you are trying to install git?

Please try the following commands in your terminal window

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install git
```

To install node js try

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```