# Install node js 8.2.1 from source in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, nodejs

I am not able to install node-v8.2.1-linux-x64.tar.xz in my Ubuntu 16.04.

I am installing node via source - I do not want an apt solution as per:

[How to install NodeJS 4 using apt?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/672994/how-to-install-nodejs-4-using-apt)

Message I am getting:-

```
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 
'/home/ubuntuser/Downloads/node-v8.2.1-linux-x64/lib/package.json'
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 
'/home/vishnu/Downloads/node-v8.2.1-linux-x64/lib/package.json'
npm WARN lib No description
npm WARN lib No repository field.
npm WARN lib No README data
npm WARN lib No license field.
```

Can anybody post the step by step installation process?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) - `node version manager`:

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.2/install.sh | bash
nvm install v8.2.1
```

Test with `node -v` :)

Comment: node -v working , nodejs -v displays program not installed why?

Comment: You will need to create a link: `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18130164/nodejs-vs-node-on-ubuntu-12-04

Comment: Ok, thanks.How can i uninstall node?I have tried this sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove node but not working

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/41429093/960623: `sudo apt-get purge node; sudo apt autoremove`

Comment: I tried uninstalling , Am facing this error now : nvm install v8.2.1
v8.2.1 is already installed.
/usr/bin/env: ‘node’: No such file or directory
nvm is not compatible with the npm config "prefix" option: currently set to ""
Run `npm config delete prefix` or `nvm use --delete-prefix v8.2.1` to unset it.

Comment: Done it, just removed nvm and reinstalled, now node installed.

Comment: i have already done upvoting the answer, but i donot have enough reputation to upvote :(

Comment: Ok so I removed my comment - stuck into the reputation spiral too :(

Answer (score 0):

I created below bash script to install nodejs ... no need to wait for nvm to make latest release available ... cat  install_node.sh

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

# ............... top of cut  ........................  install_node.sh

# export NODE_VER=v8.0.0 # matches meteor 1.4.2.3 # edit this line next time you need to update nodejs
export NODE_VER=v8.2.1

# pick parent dir of nodejs install  ... comment out or remove ONE of below
# export CODE_PARENT_DIR=/opt/code  # root owned dir ... requires you to sudo prior to npm install going forward
export CODE_PARENT_DIR=${HOME}    # RECOMMENDED

# ......... following env vars are OK no edits needed

curr_OS=$( uname )

echo curr_OS $curr_OS

if [[ "${curr_OS}" == "Darwin" ]]; then

    export OS_ARCH=darwin-x64

elif [[ "${curr_OS}" == "Linux" ]]; then

    export OS_ARCH=linux-x64
else
    echo "ERROR - failed to recognize OS $curr_OS"
    exit 5
fi

if [[ -z ${CODE_PARENT_DIR} ]]; then

    echo "ERROR - failed to see env var CODE_PARENT_DIR"
    exit 5
fi

export NODE_CODEDIR=${CODE_PARENT_DIR}/nodejs
export COMSUFFIX=tar.gz
export NODE_NAME=node-${NODE_VER}
export NODE_PARENT=${NODE_CODEDIR}/${NODE_NAME}-${OS_ARCH} 

export PATH=${NODE_PARENT}/bin:${PATH}
export NODE_PATH=${NODE_PARENT}/lib/node_modules

# ............... end of cut  ........................  install_node.sh

# put all above export lines into  ~/.bashrc file 

echo
echo "NODE_CODEDIR $NODE_CODEDIR<--"
echo

echo "mkdir -p ${NODE_CODEDIR}"
echo
      mkdir -p ${NODE_CODEDIR}
echo

echo "cd ${NODE_CODEDIR}"
      cd ${NODE_CODEDIR}
echo

# this is compiled code NOT source

[ -f ${NODE_NAME}-${OS_ARCH}.${COMSUFFIX} ] && rm ${NODE_NAME}-${OS_ARCH}.${COMSUFFIX} # if file exists remove

echo "wget -q --show-progress https://nodejs.org/download/release/${NODE_VER}/${NODE_NAME}-${OS_ARCH}.${COMSUFFIX}"
      wget -q --show-progress https://nodejs.org/download/release/${NODE_VER}/${NODE_NAME}-${OS_ARCH}.${COMSUFFIX}
echo

echo "tar -C ${NODE_CODEDIR} -xf ${NODE_NAME}-${OS_ARCH}.${COMSUFFIX}"
      tar -C ${NODE_CODEDIR} -xf ${NODE_NAME}-${OS_ARCH}.${COMSUFFIX}
echo

[ -f ${NODE_NAME}-${OS_ARCH}.${COMSUFFIX} ] && rm ${NODE_NAME}-${OS_ARCH}.${COMSUFFIX} # if file exists remove

# ...........  done ........... #

which node

node --version
```