# trying to overwrite '/usr/sbin/validlocale', which is also in package libc-bin 2.19-0ubuntu6.3

Tags: dpkg

I can´t upgrade Ubuntu because locales do not get installed:

```
root@ubuntuserver14:/home/administrator# aptitude install locales
The following packages will be upgraded:
  locales
1 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1338 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/3,942 kB of archives. After unpacking 6,903 kB will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n/?] y
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 201978 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../locales_2.19-13_all.deb ...
Unpacking locales (2.19-13) over (2.13+git20120306-12.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/locales_2.19-13_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/sbin/validlocale', which is also in package libc-bin 2.19-0ubuntu6.3
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/locales_2.19-13_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
A package failed to install.  Trying to recover:
```

**Edit**

```
administrator@ubuntuserver14:~$ apt-cache policy  locales
locales:
  Installed: 2.13+git20120306-12.1
  Candidate: 2.19-13
  Version table:
     2.19-13 0
        500 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main amd64 Packages
 *** 2.13+git20120306-12.1 0
        500 http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.13+git20120306-12 0
        500 http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: Have you added any third party ppa ? Also post the output of `apt-cache policy  locales`

Comment: I think not. 

administrator@ubuntuserver14:~$ apt-cache policy  locales
locales:
  Installed: 2.13+git20120306-12.1
  Candidate: 2.19-13
  Version table:
     2.19-13 0
        500 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main amd64 Packages
 *** 2.13+git20120306-12.1 0
        500 http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.13+git20120306-12 0
        500 http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages

Comment: Can you post it in your question by [editing your question](http://askubuntu.com/posts/573720/edit) for better readability?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [dpkg error: "trying to overwrite file, which is also in..."](http://askubuntu.com/questions/176121/dpkg-error-trying-to-overwrite-file-which-is-also-in)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have Debian repository in your source list (`ftp.us.debian.org...`) which is causing this problem.

The latest version of `locales` available in [Ubuntu 14.04 Repository](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/locales) is already installed on your system. Also this package has no [file](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/all/locales/filelist) which will replace `/usr/sbin/validlocale`

So removing this Debian repository from `/etc/apt/sources.list` should solve your problem.

After editing the `sources.list` don't forget to execute the following command.

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
```

**Or**

**(Not recommended as it can destroy your system)**

You can overwrite this file using following command

```
 sudo apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-overwrite" install locales
```

Here old `/usr/sbin/validlocale` from `libc-bin` will be overwritten by new one from `locales`.

Comment: tanks, it works