# can't install , remove , purge or anything

Tags: apt, package-management, xubuntu, software-center, libreoffice

when ever I try to open Software Center it shows a message :

> New software can't be installed because there is a problem with the
>   software currently installed. Do you want to repair this problem now?

I clicked repair but when it try to install the package it shows this error :

```
installArchives() failed: (Reading database ... 
(Reading database ... 5%
(Reading database ... 10%
(Reading database ... 15%
(Reading database ... 20%
(Reading database ... 25%
(Reading database ... 30%
(Reading database ... 35%
(Reading database ... 40%
(Reading database ... 45%
(Reading database ... 50%
(Reading database ... 55%
(Reading database ... 60%
(Reading database ... 65%
(Reading database ... 70%
(Reading database ... 75%
(Reading database ... 80%
(Reading database ... 85%
(Reading database ... 90%
(Reading database ... 95%
(Reading database ... 100%
(Reading database ... 333396 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libreoffice-common_1%3a4.3.3-0ubuntu1_all.deb ...
Unpacking libreoffice-common (1:4.3.3-0ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libreoffice-common_1%3a4.3.3-0ubuntu1_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/soffice', which is also in package openoffice-debian-menus 4.1.1-9775
rmdir: failed to remove /var/lib/libreoffice/share/prereg/: No such file or directory
rmdir: failed to remove /var/lib/libreoffice/share/: No such file or directory
rmdir: failed to remove /var/lib/libreoffice/program/: No such file or directory
rmdir: failed to remove /var/lib/libreoffice: No such file or directory
rmdir: failed to remove /var/lib/libreoffice: No such file or directory
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.55ubuntu1.1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.10.1-0ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (1.2-0ubuntu3) ...
Unknown media type in type 'all/all'
Unknown media type in type 'all/allfiles'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/mms'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/mmst'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/mmsu'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/pnm'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/rtspt'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/rtspu'
Processing triggers for gnome-icon-theme (3.12.0-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.13-1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.0.2-2) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libreoffice-common_1%3a4.3.3-0ubuntu1_all.deb
Error in function: 
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libreoffice-l10n-en-gb:
 libreoffice-l10n-en-gb depends on libreoffice-common; however:
  Package libreoffice-common is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package libreoffice-l10n-en-gb (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libreoffice-l10n-en-za:
 libreoffice-l10n-en-za depends on libreoffice-common; however:
  Package libreoffice-common is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package libreoffice-l10n-en-za (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libreoffice-l10n-ar:
 libreoffice-l10n-ar depends on libreoffice-common; however:
  Package libreoffice-common is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package libreoffice-l10n-ar (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libreoffice-help-en-gb:
 libreoffice-help-en-gb depends on libreoffice-l10n-en-gb; however:
  Package libreoffice-l10n-en-gb is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libreoffice-help-en-gb (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libreoffice-help-en-us:
 libreoffice-help-en-us depends on libreoffice-l10n-en-us; however:
  Package libreoffice-l10n-en-us is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package libreoffice-help-en-us (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libreoffice-core:
 libreoffice-core depends on libreoffice-common (>> 1:4.3.3); however:
  Package libreoffice-common is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package libreoffice-core (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-uno:
 python3-uno depends on libreoffice-core (= 1:4.3.3-0ubuntu1); however:
  Package libreoffice-core is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3-uno (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libreoffice-math:
 libreoffice-math depends on libreoffice-core (= 1:4.3.3-0ubuntu1); however:
  Package libreoffice-core is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libreoffice-math (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libreoffice-writer:
 libreoffice-writer depends on libreoffice-core (= 1:4.3.3-0ubuntu1); however:
  Package libreoffice-core is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libreoffice-writer (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mythes-en-us:
 mythes-en-us depends on libreoffice-core | openoffice.org-core (>= 1.9) | language-support-writing-en; however:
  Package libreoffice-core is not configured yet.
  Package openoffice.org-core is not installed.
  Package language-support-writing-en is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package mythes-en-us (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libreoffice-base-core:
 libreoffice-base-core depends on libreoffice-core (= 1:4.3.3-0ubuntu1); however:
  Package libreoffice-core is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libreoffice-base-core (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
```

I have already tried thiese posts :

[Getting error after installating any new software](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2117992)

[Bug Report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sysvinit/+bug/1010195?comments=all)

there is another three links but I wasn't able to put them due to reputation problem on the form :(

I know that the problem is within libreoffice packages but I can't do anything with them, can't install what they need or remove them.
tried autoremove but wasn't completed because of the dependencies since the problem here that something installed without it's dependencies ( don't know how that happen even).
any glimpse or advice is highly appreciated because if nothing worked out I'll be forced to format my PC :( and this problem would be the second to push me to this limit.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thank you so much the problem where solved , I did exactly as in the link , I just changed the package name with the one that causing the problem for me.
Thank you again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as Karel said in the comments the solution is in this link :
[dpkg error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/176121/dpkg-error-trying-to-overwrite-file-which-is-also-in)

I did exactly as mentioned but I surfed to /var/cache/apt/archives/ to check which packages casuing the problem and did the same as he did but changing the name of the package 
and every thing went well

Thanks again Karel

Answer (score 2):

It appears that OpenOffice and LibreOffice are packaged in a way, that prohibits a clean coexistence. I suggest that you settle for either of the two and remove the other.