# Help installing kubuntu-desktop on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: unity, virtualbox, kde, 16.04, kde5

Well, the problem is that I'm trying to install KDE alongside Unity on Ubuntu 16.04. I'm using the command `sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop* kdm*` but I'm not sure if this is correct. If it isn't, please correct me.

Everything goes fine until I have to choose the display manager between lightdm or sddm, no matter what I choose I get an error processing a package kde-telepathy-*something*.deb.

If I logout and login again I can change to plasma desktop but it doesn't work. It only shows a black screen with nothing I can do. If I try to install KDE again I get an error on a package `kde-telepathy-minimal.deb` which depends on `kde-config-telepathy-accounts (>= 15.04.0)` and is not going to be installed.

I'm testing this on a VirtualBox VM before I do it for real on my PC (maybe something has to do with this?).

So, has anyone successfully installed KDE alongside Unity on the new 16.04? Is it not possible yet?

Comment: I have done it successfully. It worked for a few days, then the whole OS started to crush. I would recommend you installing Kubuntu 16.04 itself, http://www.kubuntu.org/getkubuntu/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I'm using the command sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop* kdm* 
>   You should provide specific packages. If it wouldn't help, try following:

```
sudo  apt-get autoremove -y
sudo apt-get remove --purge kde-telepathy-minimal
sudo apt-get remove --purge kde-telepathy
```

And run install again. If you will face it again, do following
["Unmet dependencies" When trying to install KDE Plasma 5.3 on Ubuntu 15.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/621284/unmet-dependencies-when-trying-to-install-kde-plasma-5-3-on-ubuntu-15-04)
:

```
sudo dpkg -P unity-scope-gdrive
sudo dpkg -P account-plugin-google
sudo dpkg -P account-plugin-facebook
sudo apt-get install -f
```

PS:
Meanwhile, since the conflicting file is only and icon, it's pretty safe to override the package manager's decision with `--force-overwrite`:

```
dpkg -i --force-overwrite kde-config-telepathy-accounts_15.04.0-0ubuntu1~ubuntu15.04~ppa1_amd64.deb
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I couldn't remove telepathy because I kept getting "unmet dependencies". But it worked by removing the unity account plugins BEFORE installing kubuntu-desktop because they conflict with the ones from kde.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop
```

select lightdm as login manager

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just type

> sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop

, since you are using ubuntu 16.04, i think the command that you we're trying is been obsolete that it won't really work on the new release. please try! I'm also using ubuntu 16.04 LTS and successfully installed KDE on my desktop using that command.

Comment: I had an error with kaccounts package while installing from backports ppa on fresh 16.04.2, resulting in a black screen, fixed with sudo apt-get install -f , got some random freezes, deinstalled kde-telepathy and kaccounts-* , random freezes seem to be gone.