# Can't install KDE on Ubuntu minimal 16.04

Tags: command-line, kde

So I setup a VM on my desktop PC to test stuff before I do it on my actual installation on my laptop. I have Ubuntu minimal with the Xubuntu minimal install. I wan't to test the KDE desktop and I'm using this command `sudo apt-get install kde-plasma-desktop` to install it but it can't locate the package?

Comment: If you're still interested, look at `apt show plasma-desktop` and if you're satisfied follow up with  `sudo apt install plasma-desktop`. And let us know how things go!

Answer (score 0):

The right command is

> sudo apt-get install kde-core

If you want KDE + all the softwares that goes with it ( like Konqueror ) use

> sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop

Let me know if it worked.

**- - -EDIT- - -**

The first command no longer works since Kubuntu 9.10 release

Maybe this can help [Help installing kubuntu-desktop on Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/764542/help-installing-kubuntu-desktop-on-ubuntu-16-04?rq=1)

Comment: It didn't work, again says that it cannot locate the package. I only wan't to install the core of the DE.

Comment: My bad, the first command was revoked since Kubuntu 9.10.  Can you tell me if the second command work ? you could uninstall all the software after

Comment: Ok, now its installing it with that second command. Still, is there anyway to install just the core of the DE?

Comment: I really don't know . I looked up in the Internet but wasn't able to find a way to do so.

Comment: Ok, thanks anyway! At least I'll be able to test KDE now. I'll see a better way to install it on my laptop if I even want to after testing it.

Comment: tasksel shows an option for kubuntu full and kubuntu desktop, perhaps kubuntu desktop is just the DE?

Answer (score 0):

just avoid recommended packages, the resulting list is mostly lib* packages with very few apps.

```
sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends kubuntu-desktop
```