# Unmet dependencies and possible conflicts?

Tags: apt, package-management, xubuntu, kde, dependencies

It seems that I have messed up somewhere along the line and now I can no longer install anything without the following message showing up:

```
 The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  kde-telepathy-minimal : Depends: kde-config-telepathy-accounts (>=15.04.0) 
  but it is not going to be installed
 E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I then follow the instructions and am met with the following:

```
 $ sudo apt-get -f install
 Reading package lists... Done
 Building dependency tree       
 Reading state information... Done
 Correcting dependencies... Done
 The following additional packages will be installed:
   kde-config-telepathy-accounts
 The following NEW packages will be installed:
   kde-config-telepathy-accounts
 0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 79 not upgraded.
 695 not fully installed or removed.
 Need to get 0 B/137 kB of archives.
 After this operation, 825 kB of additional disk space will be used.
 Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
 (Reading database ... 271701 files and directories currently installed.)
 Preparing to unpack .../kde-config-telepathy-accounts_4%3a15.12.3-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
 Unpacking kde-config-telepathy-accounts (4:15.12.3-0ubuntu1) ...
 dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/kde-config-telepathy-accounts_4%3a15.12.3-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
  trying to overwrite '/usr/share/accounts/services/google-im.service', which is also in package account-plugin-google 0.12+16.04.20160126-0ubuntu1
 Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu3) ...
 Errors were encountered while processing:
  /var/cache/apt/archives/kde-config-telepathy-accounts_4%3a15.12.3-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
 E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How do I fix this?

edit 1, output from comment 1:

```
 $ sudo apt-get -s -o Debug::pkgProblemResolver=yes install kde-telepathy-minimal 
 Reading package lists... Done
 Building dependency tree       
 Reading state information... Done
 kde-telepathy-minimal is already the newest version (15.04.20ubuntu1).
 kde-telepathy-minimal set to manually installed.
 You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
 The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  kde-telepathy-minimal : Depends: kde-config-telepathy-accounts (>= 15.04.0) but it is not going to be installed
 E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

edit 2:

```
 $ sudo dpkg -Pa
 $ sudo apt-get update
 Hit:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
 Get:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease [94.5 kB]   
 Hit:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/system76-dev/stable/ubuntu xenial InRelease     
 Hit:4 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                     
 Hit:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease           
 Get:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages [213 kB]
 Get:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [94.5 kB]    
 Get:8 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main i386 Packages [209 kB]
 Get:9 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 Packages [97.1 kB]
 Get:10 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe i386 Packages [94.3 kB]
 Fetched 802 kB in 3s (230 kB/s)                        
 Reading package lists... Done
 W: Target Packages (partner/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:45 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial-partner.list:4
 W: Target Packages (partner/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:45 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial-partner.list:4
 W: Target Packages (partner/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:45 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial-partner.list:4
 W: Target Translations (partner/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:45 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial-partner.list:4
 W: Target Translations (partner/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:45 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial-partner.list:4
 W: Target DEP-11 (partner/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:45 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial-partner.list:4
 W: Target DEP-11-icons (partner/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:45 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial-partner.list:4
 W: Target Packages (partner/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:45 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial-partner.list:4
 W: Target Packages (partner/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:45 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial-partner.list:4
 W: Target Packages (partner/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:45 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial-partner.list:4
 W: Target Translations (partner/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:45 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial-partner.list:4
 W: Target Translations (partner/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:45 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial-partner.list:4
 W: Target DEP-11 (partner/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:45 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial-partner.list:4
 W: Target DEP-11-icons (partner/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:45 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/xenial-partner.list:4
```

edit 3: Motte001's solution fixed the problem

Comment: output listed in edit 1

Comment: Ok, done. None of the fixes in the link worked. They all gave the same message.  To answer your other question, this happens whenever I try to install anything i.e.  "sudo apt-get install <any package>"

Comment: Added edit 2 to reflect last comment. Same error messages still occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue, when installing `kubuntu-desktop`. I found the fix on Askubuntu.

Form here: https://askubuntu.com/a/621295/532133

```
sudo dpkg -P unity-scope-gdrive
sudo dpkg -P account-plugin-google
sudo dpkg -P account-plugin-facebook
sudo apt-get install -f
```