# apt equivalent of `brew doctor`?

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

I recently ran the command `sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop -y` on an Ubuntu 16.04 virtual machine. There were some conflicts between some of the dependencies of `kubuntu-desktop` and some of the unity lens Google drive and Facebook integration and maybe a few other things. Unfortunately apt did not catch these inconsistencies until the installation was already partially underway. I had to spend about fifteen minutes `dpkg -r`-ing conflicting packages with very little idea what I was actually doing
. I can now kind of sort of log in, but I'd like to audit my packages to see if anything is a "weird" state and requires some kind of intervention.

Comment: Related https://askubuntu.com/questions/621284/unmet-dependencies-when-trying-to-install-kde-plasma-5-3-on-ubuntu-15-04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `dpkg -C` or `dpkg --audit` to check for broken packages.