# KDE Plasma Install is Stuck - plasma-desktop package cannot be installed

Tags: package-management, dpkg, kde, dependencies

I had this [problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/621284/unmet-dependencies-when-trying-to-install-kde-plasma-5-3-on-ubuntu-15-04) and I followed the first solution.

I'm closer to a solution, but now plasma desktop won't install. I ran this command `sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop` again and this is the result:

```
Reading package lists... Done  
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done  
kubuntu-desktop is already the newest version (1.338).  
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:  
The following packages have unmet dependencies.  
kubuntu-desktop : Depends: plasma-desktop but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

So I ran `sudo apt-get -f install` and got this:

```
Reading package lists... Done  
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done  
Correcting dependencies... Done  
The following additional packages will be installed:  
  plasma-desktop  
The following NEW packages will be installed  
  plasma-desktop  
0 to upgrade, 1 to newly install, 0 to remove and 232 not to upgrade.  
1 not fully installed or removed.  
Need to get 0 B/1,541 kB of archives.  
After this operation, 8,084 kB of additional disk space will be used.  
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y  
(Reading database ... 295821 files and directories currently installed.)  
Preparing to unpack .../plasma-  desktop_4%3a5.6.5-0ubuntu1~ubuntu16.04~ppa1_amd64.deb ...  
Unpacking plasma-desktop (4:5.6.5-0ubuntu1~ubuntu16.04~ppa1) ...  
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/plasma-desktop_4%3a5.6.5-0ubuntu1~ubuntu16.04~ppa1_amd64.deb (--unpack):  
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/qml/org/kde/activities/settings/libkactivitiessettingsplugin.so', which is also in package qml-module-org-kde-activities:amd64 5.18.0-0ubuntu1  
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)  
Processing triggers for dbus (1.10.6-1ubuntu3) ...  
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.3~bzr0+16.04.20160824-0ubuntu1) ...  
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...  
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-6ubuntu3.1) ...  
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu5) ...  
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.59ubuntu1) ...  
Errors were encountered while processing:  
 /var/cache/apt/archives/plasma-desktop_4%3a5.6.5-0ubuntu1~ubuntu16.04~ppa1_amd64.deb  
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

What should I do next?

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar problem.

Try the following command:

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/plasma-desktop_4%3a5.6.5-0ubuntu1~ubuntu16.04~ppa1_amd64.deb

sudo apt-get -f install
```

This should do :)