# Unmet dependencies

Tags: 14.04, dependencies

While updating Ubuntu 14.04, I came across the following error message:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 collada-dom-dev : Depends: collada-dom2.4-sp-dev but it is not installed
 collada-dom2.4-sp : Depends: collada-dom2.4-sp-dev but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit**:

After it fails to install the missing package, using:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

I get this message:

```
Unpacking collada-dom2.4-sp-dev (2.4.4.1-ubuntu1~trusty1) ... 
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/collada-dom2.4-sp-dev_2.4.4.1-ubuntu1~trusty1_i386.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/cmake/collada_dom-2.4/collada_dom-config.cmake', which is also in package collada-dom2.4-dp-dev 2.4.4.0-ubuntu1~trusty1 
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe) 
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/collada-dom2.4-sp-dev_2.4.4.1-ubuntu1~trusty1_i386.deb 
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: 'Try using -f' so: `sudo apt-get install -f`

Comment: I tried that, and I was prompted to install the missing program/package, but it never installs no matter how many times I try.

Comment: After it fails to install the missing package, I get this message:

Comment: Unpacking collada-dom2.4-sp-dev (2.4.4.1-ubuntu1~trusty1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/collada-dom2.4-sp-dev_2.4.4.1-ubuntu1~trusty1_i386.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/cmake/collada_dom-2.4/collada_dom-config.cmake', which is also in package collada-dom2.4-dp-dev 2.4.4.0-ubuntu1~trusty1
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/collada-dom2.4-sp-dev_2.4.4.1-ubuntu1~trusty1_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Answer (score 6):

Moving aside the sources.list.d seems to be a fix that may not be desirable, and may actually not fix the root problem. Especially if there are sources in there that you actually want to keep. I think this is the better answer: [dpkg error: "trying to overwrite file, which is also in..."](https://askubuntu.com/questions/176121/dpkg-error-trying-to-overwrite-file-which-is-also-in)

For this particular problem I used:

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/collada-dom2.4-sp-dev_2.4.4.1-ubuntu1~trusty1_amd64.deb
```

Note: you'll want to replace the .deb file with the one your system is complaining about. Still don't know what is actually causing this problem with updates today...?

Comment: in simple words the system gets *confused* as you already have the similar or the same package that you're trying to install in your system which you most likely installed manually using *sudo* priveleges, it wasn't installed from official repos or ppas that's why usually this incident occurs. When you install packages manually from *.deb* file or any other you should clearly understand what you are doing/installing to avoid these incidents in the future.

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be related to ROS, the Robot Operating System, the main user of Collada.  It may be a problem with having both ROS-Indigo and Ros-Jade (different versions) installed.  After doing the suggested

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/collada-dom2.4-sp-dev_2.4.4.1-ubuntu1~trusty1_amd64.deb
```

to unjam the package system, I did a "sudo apt-get autoremove", which removed lots of old ROS-Indigo stuff.  After that, "sudo apt-get check" showed no errors.

Comment: this is just a copy of @colby's answer above. Read the good answers before posting yours.

Comment: But it speaks of a probable common cause. I think it was caused by ROS for me too.

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem. Apparently, I had third party repositories which were causing the problem. I removed them with the following:

```
sudo mv /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ /etc/apt/sources.list.d.bk/
sudo mkdir /etc/apt/sources.list.d/
```

I then ran `sudo apt-get install -f`

Answer (score 0):

Answer proposed by @colby worked for me. Had to do

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the Package: `sudo apt-get remove collada-dom2.4-sp`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem under 14.04 LTS after I did a "sudo apt-get dist-upgrade".  The cause apparently was some old linux headers and kernels that needed to be purged.  The solution in my case was "sudo apt-get -f autoremove".