# problem installing Collada-dom 2.4.4 headers and build tools

Tags: 14.04, apt, package-management, dependencies

I got a notification that I need to install updates, and I clicked yes, but since then I am getting this stop sign on the top right corner because of unmet dependencies. 
when i run:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

I get bunch of packages to be removed and then:

```
The following extra packages will be installed:
  collada-dom2.4-sp-dev
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  collada-dom2.4-sp-dev
```

When I click yes:

```
Selecting previously unselected package collada-dom2.4-sp-dev.
(Reading database ... 306874 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../collada-dom2.4-sp-dev_2.4.4.1-ubuntu1~trusty1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking collada-dom2.4-sp-dev (2.4.4.1-ubuntu1~trusty1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/collada-dom2.4-sp-dev_2.4.4.1-ubuntu1~trusty1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/cmake/collada_dom-2.4/collada_dom-config.cmake', which is also in package collada-dom2.4-dp-dev 2.4.4.0-ubuntu1~trusty1
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/collada-dom2.4-sp-dev_2.4.4.1-ubuntu1~trusty1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

when I run `sudo apt-get autoremove` I get:

```
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 collada-dom-dev : Depends: collada-dom2.4-sp-dev but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Check this answer: works better -> https://askubuntu.com/questions/176121/dpkg-error-trying-to-overwrite-file-which-is-also-in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following worked for me:

`sudo dpkg --purge --force-all collada-dom2.4-sp-dev`

Then try

`sudo apt-get install -f`

I found this solution on the ROS forums at [collada-dom2.4-sp-dev causes dist-upgrade to fail on ubuntu 14.04](http://answers.ros.org/question/222892/collada-dom24-sp-dev-causes-dist-upgrade-to-fail-on-ubuntu-1404/.) Check there for more information.

Comment: Note, the package in question for me was `collada-dom2.4-dp-dev`.