# Error in libreoffice directory after "sudo apt-get -f install"

Tags: kubuntu, libreoffice, xfce

I'm trying to -f install and it's returning an error in the libreoffice directory, even though I don't have it installed anymore. This is the error:

```
yuri@Yuri-Laptop:~$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libreoffice-common
Suggested packages:
  libreoffice-style-breeze libreoffice-style-hicontrast
  libreoffice-style-human libreoffice-style-oxygen libreoffice-style-sifr
  libreoffice-style-tango
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libreoffice-common
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
9 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/22,3 MB of archives.
After this operation, 84,8 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 301323 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libreoffice-common_1%3a5.1.4-0ubuntu1_all.deb ...
Unpacking libreoffice-common (1:5.1.4-0ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libreoffice-common_1%3a5.1.4-0ubuntu1_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/soffice', which is also in package openoffice-debian-menus 4.1.2-9782
rmdir: failed to remove '/var/lib/libreoffice/share/prereg/': No such file or directory
rmdir: failed to remove '/var/lib/libreoffice/share/': No such file or directory
rmdir: failed to remove '/var/lib/libreoffice/program/': No such file or directory
rmdir: failed to remove '/var/lib/libreoffice': No such file or directory
rmdir: failed to remove '/var/lib/libreoffice': No such file or directory
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-6ubuntu3.1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu5) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.59ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (1.5-2ubuntu0.1) ...
Unknown media type in type 'all/all'
Unknown media type in type 'all/allfiles'
Processing triggers for gnome-icon-theme (3.12.0-1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.15-0ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libreoffice-common_1%3a5.1.4-0ubuntu1_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [dpkg error: "trying to overwrite file, which is also in..."](https://askubuntu.com/questions/176121/dpkg-error-trying-to-overwrite-file-which-is-also-in)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the problem. I installed aptitude, so I just need to upgrade the system.

> sudo aptitude dist-upgrade

After that, the dependecies were resolved.

Comment: Then you better mark your answer like the correct one

Comment: @Borislav thanks for reminding me. It's been so long that I had already forgotten.