# Unable to install Kodi on Ubuntu Mate 16.04

Tags: kodi

I am trying to insall Kodi but I keep getting the following:

```
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 420573 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../kodi_2%3a16.1~git20160425.1001-final-0xenial_all.deb ...
Unpacking kodi (2:16.1~git20160425.1001-final-0xenial) over (15.2+dfsg1-3ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/kodi_2%3a16.1~git20160425.1001-final-0xenial_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/xsessions/kodi.desktop', which is also in package kodi-data 15.2+dfsg1-3ubuntu1
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.3~bzr0+16.04.20160824-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu5) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.59ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/kodi_2%3a16.1~git20160425.1001-final-0xenial_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

What is this and how can I fix it?

I tried sudo apt-get install -f and still the same

Comment: Looks like you'll need to uninstall Kodi 15.2 first.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [dpkg error: "trying to overwrite file, which is also in..."](https://askubuntu.com/questions/176121/dpkg-error-trying-to-overwrite-file-which-is-also-in)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're trying to install Kodi from different package sources and with a different package structure. This can cause problems when you're trying to replace one with the other in a straight forward manner. You should be able to resolve the issue by removing the existing Kodi packages before you install the new ones:

```
sudo apt remove kodi\*
sudo dpkg -i /path/to/kodi.deb
```

If the last step results in unsatisfied dependencies you can have Apt resolve them:

```
sudo apt install -f
```