# Ubuntu 16.04, installing updates returned an error code (1)

Tags: apt, upgrade, dpkg, crash

I was doing routine update && upgrade procedure on Ubuntu 16.04 and it wanted to upgrade some multimedia codec libraries

[image: List of libraries to be updated]

I confirmed the upgrade as seen in the picture above. Then the upgrade process returned error code (1) and couldn't finish upgrading.

[image: Broken Pipe, /usr/bin/dpkg returns an error code]

Now I am getting this unmet dependency thing when I try to do anything related to upgrade.

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libavcodec-extra57 : Depends: libx265-102 (>= 2.2) but it is not installed
 x265 : Depends: libx265-102 (>= 2.2) but it is not installed
        Depends: libx265-102 (< 2.3) but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

I am concerned. Is it possible to revert to the state before I try to upgrade?

Comment: cannot put more than 2 links, not insert images as images without links!, if my rep increases, I will edit the post.

Comment: Could you please post text files, dialogue messages, and program output listings as text, not as images? To achieve the latter two you can either 1) select, copy & paste the dialogue text or terminal content or 2) [save the program output to a file](//askubuntu.com/q/420981/175814) and use that. Longer listings (≥100 lines) should be uploaded to a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) and linked to in the question. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa)

Comment: I edited the (since now I have enough rep), If the content of the terminals are not enough. I don't know what I can do more. Because I managed to solve my issue as stated in my own answer. However, if you have an explanation what is going on and why that magic command resolve it. I am still interested to know. Hence I didn't accept my answer as an answer!

Comment: @DavidFoerster, thank you for the link. it was extensive compilation of solutions to my previous(other) problems with unmet dependencies. However, my main issue was the error which is the 'Broken Pipe', I got during 'update' procedure.

Comment: That's the first time I hear about this problem from you. I don't see any `apt-get update` output anywhere in your question so it was impossible to know. Could you please [edit] your question to include the *full, verbatim* output of `sudo apt-get update`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have solved my issue by following [dpkg overwrite](https://askubuntu.com/questions/176121/dpkg-error-trying-to-overwrite-file-which-is-also-in)

Specifically I entered:

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/libx265-102_2.2-1~16.04.york0_amd64.deb
```

Comment: I am not hundred percent sure that this is safe and applicable to all similar cases. If someone explains what was going on and why did this comment solved it. I can accept it as an answer.

Comment: The above command solved this issue for me too.

Answer (score 1):

Let's try to clear up the 'partial' error first. Be very careful with these commands:

```
sudo rm -vf /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/*  # Remove files in 'partial'
sudo rm -vf /var/lib/apt/lists/*  # Remove package lists in 'lists'
sudo apt-get update
```

If you are still getting a 'status' error, try restoring a backup copy of the file:

```
sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/status /var/lib/dpkg/status.0715
sudo cp /var/backups/dpkg.status.0 /var/lib/dpkg/status
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: Neither of them worked. I am still getting the same errors, unfortunately!