# libavcodec57 causing major dependency problems with ffmpeg

Tags: 16.04, server, apt, dependencies, ffmpeg

I'm running Ubuntu Server 16.04 with Emby using ffmpeg. Just yesterday, I started getting the below error when running sudo apt-get update/upgrade. I'm somewhat new to Linux, but I've tried a huge variety of apt-get autoclean, clean, autoremove, etc. I also found a site that suggested installing jessie-backports and re-installing ffmpeg from there (or something called qtox) but i didn't seem to have any luck with that.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libavcodec57 : Depends: libx265-102 (>= 2.2) but it is not going to be installed
 x265 : Depends: libx265-102 (>= 2.2) but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: libx265-102 (< 2.3) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I got close to using force-remove-reinstreq on libavcodec57, but I figured I should ask the experts first.

Anyone have any advice on things to try? Emby seems to still be working fine (I've gotten a few video errors but that's probably due to some of my files being messed up, not so much Emby)

Edit: and when I run apt-get -f install, i get the below

```
Unpacking libx265-102:amd64 (2.2-1~16.04.york0) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libx265-102_2.2-1~16.04.york0_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libx265.so.102', which is also in package libx265-95:amd64 2.2-0~16.04.york0
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu5) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libx265-102_2.2-1~16.04.york0_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu 16.04, installing updates returned an error code (1)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/873093/ubuntu-16-04-installing-updates-returned-an-error-code-1)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/opencv\_haartraining', which is also in package libopencv2.3-bin 2.3.1+svn6514+branch23-12~oneiric](http://askubuntu.com/questions/195950/trying-to-overwrite-usr-bin-opencv-haartraining-which-is-also-in-package-lib)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up using a combination of answers from two different previous posts to sold my problem. The post that was linked as a duplicate led me to this: [trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/opencv_haartraining', which is also in package libopencv2.3-bin 2.3.1+svn6514+branch23-12~oneiric](https://askubuntu.com/questions/195950/trying-to-overwrite-usr-bin-opencv-haartraining-which-is-also-in-package-lib/430443#430443) . I was able to use the solution listed by the OP, first running

```
sudo dpkg -P libx265-95:amd64
```

then i ran

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

followed by

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

I got a RAID error upon upgrading about unbootable system, but luckily I have my system booting from my SSD, not my HDD RAID1 array. So I rebooted the server and everything seems to have come back up successfully. Thanks for the help, much love!

Comment: It's better to just put your answer in your answer instead of your question.