# gimp 2.9.5 failed to update (2017-01-31)

Tags: gimp, beta

http://ppa.launchpad.net/otto-kesselgulasch/gimp-edge/ubuntu

gimp 2.9.5 failed to update properly, and attempting to fix it with the general remedy proposed all over askubuntu fails, like this:

```
$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  gimp
Suggested packages:
  gimp-help-en | gimp-help
The following packages will be upgraded:
  gimp
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/3 548 kB of archives.
After this operation, 37,9 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 220805 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../gimp_2.9.5~79-0x21~ppa~5170980_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gimp (2.9.5~79-0x21~ppa~5170980) over (2.9.5~71-0x0~ppa~00faf17) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/gimp_2.9.5~79-0x21~ppa~5170980_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/gimp/2.0/plug-ins/wavelet-decompose', which is also in package gimp-plugin-registry 7.20140602ubuntu2
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/gimp_2.9.5~79-0x21~ppa~5170980_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
$
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [dpkg error: "trying to overwrite file, which is also in..."](https://askubuntu.com/questions/176121/dpkg-error-trying-to-overwrite-file-which-is-also-in)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The remedy is something like this, (I did more, but these steps seemed to be the steps that actually did it).

```
$ sudo apt-get update
...
Fetched 102 kB in 0s (110 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done

$ sudo apt-get purge --remove gimp gimp-gmic gimp-plugin-registry  # the related packages
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  gimp-data libamd2.4.1 libbabl-0.1-0 libcamd2.4.1 libccolamd2.9.1 libcholmod3.0.6 libgegl-0.3-0 libgimp2.0
  libmypaint libtiff-tools libumfpack5.7.1 libwebp6 libwebpdemux2 libwebpmux2
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  gimp* gimp-gmic* gimp-plugin-registry*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 3 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 26,8 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 220804 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing gimp-gmic (1:1.8.0~pre-0x0~ppa~edge) ...
Removing gimp-plugin-registry (7.20140602ubuntu2) ...
Removing gimp (2.9.5~71-0x0~ppa~00faf17) ...
Purging configuration files for gimp (2.9.5~71-0x0~ppa~00faf17) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.3~bzr0+16.04.20160824-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-6ubuntu3.1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu5) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.59ubuntu1) ...
Setting up gimp-data (2.9.5~79-0x21~ppa~5170980) ...
Setting up libgegl-0.3-0:amd64 (1:0.3.11~45-0x3~ppa~39ea9fd) ...
Setting up libgimp2.0 (2.9.5~79-0x21~ppa~5170980) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu5) ...

$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Answer (score 1):

As indicated by this line:

```
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/gimp_2.9.5~79-0x21~ppa~5170980_amd64.deb (--unpack): trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/gimp/2.0/plug-ins/wavelet-decompose', which is also in package  7.20140602ubuntu2 dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
```

the problem is that the new version of the `gimp` package provides a file which is also provided by the `gimp-plugin-registry` package, and so they cannot be installed together, and `gimp-plugin-registry` must be removed before the new version of `gimp` can be installed.

Answer (score 1):

I used synaptic to "completely remove" the plugin registry. Seemed to work.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer similar to @Hannu's, but alas I cannot comment. Mainly the difference was I had to reinstall all the packages I purged.

```
sudo aptitude purge gimp gimp-gmic gimp-plugin-registry
sudo aptitude upgrade
sudo aptitude install gimp gimp-gmic gimp-plugin-registry
```