# Broken dependencies stopping me from installing Emulation Station

Tags: updates, dependencies

I'm not sure what caused this to happen, but it occurred after Ubuntu attempted to install kernel updates.  I could no longer boot with the newest kernel.  I booted with a previous kernel, cleared some space (the reason the update failed) and I could boot again.  However, now I'm left with a broken package.

Simultaneously I was attempting to install Emulation Station.  I got some errors during install which prompted me to clear space, which led to the above issue.

Finally, I'm left with a broken package that is hindering me from installing any new software.  libsdl2-dev is broken according to synaptic and it can't seem to repair it.  I attempted to reinstall via synaptic and had no luck.  The following error is from letting it attempt repair:

```
(Reading database ... 385577 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libsdl2-2.0-0_2.0.2+dfsg1-3ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libsdl2-2.0-0:amd64 (2.0.2+dfsg1-3ubuntu1.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libsdl2-2.0-0_2.0.2+dfsg1-3ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL2-2.0.so.0', which is also in package libsdl2:amd64 2.0.3+z4~20140315-8621-1ppa1precise1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libsdl2-2.0-0_2.0.2+dfsg1-3ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb
Error in function: 
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libsdl2-dev:
 libsdl2-dev depends on libsdl2-2.0-0 (= 2.0.2+dfsg1-3ubuntu1.1); however:
  Package libsdl2-2.0-0:amd64 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package libsdl2-dev (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
```

I've searched Google and found no posts regarding this specific dependency/package.

Comment: sudo apt-get -f install yields
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/universe libsdl2-2.0-0 amd64 2.0.2+dfsg1-3ubuntu1.1 [317 kB]
Fetched 317 kB in 0s (1,246 kB/s)     
(Reading database ... 385577 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libsdl2-2.0-0_2.0.2+dfsg1-3ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb ...

Comment: Unpacking libsdl2-2.0-0:amd64 (2.0.2+dfsg1-3ubuntu1.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libsdl2-2.0-0_2.0.2+dfsg1-3ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL2-2.0.so.0', which is also in package libsdl2:amd64 2.0.3+z4~20140315-8621-1ppa1precise1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libsdl2-2.0-0_2.0.2+dfsg1-3ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [dpkg error: "trying to overwrite file, which is also in..."](https://askubuntu.com/questions/176121/dpkg-error-trying-to-overwrite-file-which-is-also-in)

Answer (score 0):

**The immediate problem** is written in plain language in your error message:

```
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libsdl2-2.0-0_2.0.2+dfsg1-3ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb (--unpack): trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL2-2.0.so.0', which is also in package libsdl2:amd64 2.0.3+z4~20140315-8621-1ppa1precise1
```

Okay, that actually could be plainer. Let's say it again without all the complicated filenames:

```
dpkg: error processing NEW_PACKAGE: trying to overwrite FILE, which is also in OLD_PACKAGE
```

Each file in your system can be provided by one (and only one) package at a time. When more than one package tries to provide the same file, those packages *conflict*.

In other words, NEW_PACKAGE and OLD_PACKAGE conflict. They both try to provide the same FILE.

**The deeper problem** is that you are adding PPAs and other Non-Ubuntu sources that provide conflicting packages.

Example: Your old libsdl2 is `libsdl2:amd64 2.0.3+z4~20140315-8621-1ppa1precise1`.

- It's a 12.04 package on a 14.04 system (bad!)
- It's a PPA package providing a key system service (bad!)
- The PPA package uses a weird, nonstandard versioning that doesn't quite match either Ubuntu nor Debian (bad!)

A couple of these, and you are well on the road to a broken system and a full reinstall.

The easiest way to avoid this problem is to minimize the use of PPAs and stick to the tested, compatible Ubuntu repos.

**How to fix** your immediate problem:

1. Find that PPA in your apt sources. Delete it. It's not your friend anymore.
2. Uninstall **all** packages provided by that PPA.
3. Since you changed your sources, refresh your package database (`sudo apt-get update`)
4. Reinstall the removed software, this time from the Ubuntu repos (`sudo apt-get install <whatever>`)