# Can't install packages after changing to KDE on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: apt, dpkg

After installing KDE on Ubuntu 16.04 I can't use unity anymore and when trying to download new software with apt-get I get error messages.

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
kde-telepathy-minimal : Depends: kde-config-telepathy-accounts (>=15.04.0) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

When I try `sudo apt-get -f install` i get another error message.

```
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 46 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/137 kB of archives.
After this operation, 825 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [J/n] j
(Reading database ... 445397 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../kde-config-telepathy-accounts_4%3a15.12.3-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking kde-config-telepathy-accounts (4:15.12.3-0ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/kde-config-telepathy-accounts_4%3a15.12.3-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
trying to overwrite '/usr/share/accounts/services/google-im.service', which is also in package account-plugin-google 0.12+16.04.20160126-0ubuntu1
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu7) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
/var/cache/apt/archives/kde-config-telepathy-accounts_4%3a15.12.3-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb                                                                 
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I'm pretty sure i messed something up along the way and I read online that I will have to delete the damaged package but I don't really know how to do that without bricking my system.

Comment: Follow the David Xia's answer there. You basically need to use `sudo apt-get install -f -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-overwrite"`

Comment: Although this is a duplicate answer, I would like to comment one thing, `--force-overwrite`  will be my last option. Better go for [Avinash's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/433510/146791).

Answer (score 0):

What it says: Installing kde-config-telepathy-accounts tries to (over)write the file `/usr/share/accounts/services/google-im.service`, which also are in the package account-plugin-google .. this is a conflict between unity / gnome and KDE packages.

You can remove account-plugin-google (`sudo apt remove account-plugin-google`) or just remove the file (`sudo rm /usr/share/accounts/services/google-im.service`) and hope that the two packages can exist together ..

And in either case, rerun `sudo apt-get -f install`