# Cannot revert graphics drivers after trying to upgrade using the oibaf PPA on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: ppa, 17.10, amdgpu

I am having issues after sudo apt upgrade failed to install complete packages. I tried purging the ppa to revert the drivers to no avial.

```
Correcting dependencies... failed. The following packages have unmet dependencies:  libgl1-mesa-dri : Depends: libdrm-amdgpu1 (>=
2.4.85+git1710271830.33dcc2~gd~a) but 2.4.83-1 is installed  mesa-va-drivers : Depends: libdrm-amdgpu1 (>=
2.4.85+git1710271830.33dcc2~gd~a) but 2.4.83-1 is installed  mesa-vdpau-drivers : Depends: libdrm-amdgpu1 (>=
2.4.85+git1710271830.33dcc2~gd~a) but 2.4.83-1 is installed 
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages. 
E: Unable to correct dependencies 
$ sudo dpkg --purge libdrm-common dpkg: warning: ignoring request to remove libdrm-common which isn't installed 
$ sudo ppa-purge  ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers Updating packages lists PPA to be removed: oibaf graphics-drivers 
Warning:  Could not find package list for PPA: oibaf graphics-drivers
```

I tried purging and re-adding the ppa several times. I tried "-f install",  "autoremove", "pkg --configure -a".

I tried fixing in synaptic, only to find more errors.
[image]

All I want to do at this point is get rid of this ppa & revert to the old packages.

I believe my problem lies here:

Preparing to unpack .../libdrm-amdgpu1_2.4.85+git1710311403.33dcc2~gd~a_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libdrm-amdgpu1:amd64 (2.4.85+git1710311403.33dcc2~gd~a) over (2.4.83-1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libdrm-amdgpu1_2.4.85+git1710311403.33dcc2~gd~a_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/libdrm/amdgpu.ids', which is also in package libdrm-common 2.4.85+git1710311403.33dcc2~gd~a
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libdrm-amdgpu1_2.4.85+git1710311403.33dcc2~gd~a_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

The Oibaf PPA is [here](https://launchpad.net/~oibaf/+archive/ubuntu/graphics-drivers).

Screenshot after purging the PPA:
[image]

**EDIT**:I have since wiped my hard drive and re-installed Ubuntu 17.10. And, I found a post explaining, "[How To Install The Latest AMDGPU-PRO Drivers On Linux](http://www.technologypapa.com/how-to-install-the-latest-amdgpu-pro-drivers-on-linux/)" but, I have not attempted to try it yet.

Comment: Install `ppa-purge` and run it against the same PPA you added. It will: 1. Remove the PPA and 2. Remove or downgrade any packages installed via that PPA.

Comment: Sorry, I tried that and y-ppa manager, as well. You can see by the last screenshot, I purged the PPA. The bottom of the PPA page says, "=== Revert to original drivers ===
To revert to standard Ubuntu drivers type the following in a prompt shell:
$ sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
$ sudo ppa-purge ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers"

Comment: It seems Obaif's is not the only PPA you added. The error message mentions "xorg-edgers". Mixing different PPAs for graphics drivers shouldn't be done and yours is a typical result of conflicting packages. Try removing/purging the other PPA before.

Comment: The other PPA didn't add anything or take anything from the system, I removed (purged) that one, as well. I only added that one to try to fix the errors from Obaif's.

Comment: To try to fix? No, it actually made the problem worse.

Comment: No, it actually didn't. The problem was there before I added it. It doesn't matter now. I wiped the hard drive and re-installed ubuntu 17.10.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [dpkg error: "trying to overwrite file, which is also in..."](https://askubuntu.com/questions/176121/dpkg-error-trying-to-overwrite-file-which-is-also-in)

Answer (score 1):

This worked to me so after run the following command, it successfully upgraded with oibaf PPA
https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=253257

```
dpkg-divert --package libdrm-common --divert /usr/share/libdrm/amdgpu.ids.divert --rename /usr/share/libdrm/amdgpu.ids
```