# 16.04: Login stuck in loop

Tags: 16.04, apt, login, steam, amd-graphics

Attempting to install steam and optimized drivers from Oibaf PPA, I was faced with a loop at login, where entering my credentials would briefly display a command-line and then return the login screen with fields emptied.

Comment: Thanks I did try this solution also, but it didn't work. I have posted an answer but can't accept it until tomorrow.

Comment: Which solution did you try specifically? The linked question has about 30 answers. On the other hand your own answer resembles none of them so I'll retract my close vote.

Comment: Sorry. To clarify, I mean I tried the accepted answer. Tried most of the lightdm- and fglrx-related answers too but no luck. I only posted here because I have not found this solution as a whole elsewhere and the internet seems saturated with snippets of answers, as in the question referenced. Been on stackexchange a while but not on this forum. Let me know if I need to re-write the question!

Comment: Thanks for the update and clarification! While it's not critical it may help future readers if you [edit] your question to add the specific steps and results of your failed attempt. It would also help to demonstrate to reviewers that your question is no duplicate of the linked question. Overall it’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd>, I was able to access the CLI and discovered errors similar to those found within [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/971343/cannot-revert-graphics-drivers-after-trying-to-upgrade-using-the-oibaf-ppa-on-ub).

I deleted the Oibaf entries from `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`.

This had no effect. As this was not the only repository I had newly been working from, I added the repository again to maintain continuity in troubleshooting.

Following luke's solution [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/971343/cannot-revert-graphics-drivers-after-trying-to-upgrade-using-the-oibaf-ppa-on-ub) I still had the same issue.

I was able to login to the desktop again after running the following command:

```
sudo apt -f upgrade
```

Note:

For some implementations of the amd drivers, they can be reverted by entering

```
amdgpu-pro-uninstall
```