# How to solve "dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libvlccore9_4.0.0~rc1~~git20171225+r73378+113~ubuntu16.04.1_amd64.deb (--unpack)"

Tags: apt

Getting errors running `sudo apt-get -f install`:

```
"Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  gstreamer1.0-plugins-base:i386 libcdparanoia0:i386 libdbusmenu-qt2:i386 libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0:i386 libgstreamer1.0-0:i386 libopus0:i386 liborc-0.4-0:i386 libqt4-opengl:i386
  libqtwebkit4:i386 libtheora0:i386 libvisual-0.4-0:i386 libvlccore8 libxss1:i386 libxv1:i386 linux-headers-4.4.0-101 linux-headers-4.4.0-101-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-96
  linux-headers-4.4.0-96-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-97 linux-headers-4.4.0-97-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-98 linux-headers-4.4.0-98-generic linux-image-4.4.0-101-generic linux-image-4.4.0-96-generic
  linux-image-4.4.0-97-generic linux-image-4.4.0-98-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-101-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-96-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-97-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-98-generic
  sni-qt:i386 vlc-plugin-notify vlc-plugin-samba vlc-plugin-video-splitter vlc-plugin-visualization
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libvlccore9
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libvlccore9
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 25 not upgraded.
14 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/472 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,240 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y    
(Reading database ... 462617 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libvlccore9_4.0.0~rc1~~git20171225+r73378+113~ubuntu16.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libvlccore9:amd64 (4.0.0~rc1~~git20171225+r73378+113~ubuntu16.04.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libvlccore9_4.0.0~rc1~~git20171225+r73378+113~ubuntu16.04.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvlccore.so.9.0.0', which is also in package libvlccore8:amd64 3.0.0~~git20171210+r73147+99~ubuntu16.04.1
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu9) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libvlccore9_4.0.0~rc1~~git20171225+r73378+113~ubuntu16.04.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)"
```

Tried several options and could not fix it.
Any help appreciated!

Thx

Comment: The error is clearly stated: `/var/cache/apt/archives/libvlccore9_4.0.0~rc1~~git20171225+r73378+113~ubuntu16.04.1_amd64.deb (--unpack): trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvlccore.so.9.0.0', which is also in package libvlccore8:amd64 3.0.0~~git20171210+r73147+99~ubuntu16.04.1` You must decide which of those packages (and sources)you really want, and remove the other.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I am not too familiar with packages management.  I see your point.  But how to I specify "which of those packages (and sources)you really want, and remove the other" ?

Comment: user29288008 raises a crucial quesition: how can you remove a package?  What exact command do I type?

Answer (score 12):

Had the same problem and this fixed it:

`sudo dpkg -P libvlccore8`

Then again `sudo apt-get -f install`

Comment: Wonder how you figured out that "libvlccore8" had do be purged?

Comment: see here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/176121/dpkg-error-trying-to-overwrite-file-which-is-also-in?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Instead of libvlccore8 I had a problem with cmake, and `sudo dpkg -P cmake` fixed it. Thanks!