# How to solve ? dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libc-bin_2.31-0ubuntu9.14_arm64.deb (--unpack):

Tags: 20.04, dpkg

I was trying to do a `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade` on my Ubuntu and end up with the following error

```bash
$ sudo apt update 
Get:1 file:/var/cudnn-local-tegra-repo-ubuntu2004-8.6.0.166  InRelease [1,575 B]
Get:1 file:/var/cudnn-local-tegra-repo-ubuntu2004-8.6.0.166  InRelease [1,575 B]
Hit:2 https://cli.github.com/packages stable InRelease
Get:3 https://repo.download.nvidia.com/jetson/common r35.4 InRelease [2,555 B]                                                                                                            
Hit:4 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                                                                            
Get:5 https://repo.download.nvidia.com/jetson/t234 r35.4 InRelease [2,547 B]                                   
Hit:6 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal InRelease                                                     
Get:7 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates InRelease [114 kB]
Hit:8 http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:9 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-backports InRelease
Hit:10 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-security InRelease
Fetched 119 kB in 2s (64.5 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
1 package can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see it.
```

The one package that can be upgraded was `libc-bin`.

```bash
$ apt list --upgradable 
Listing... Done
libc-bin/focal-updates,focal-security 2.31-0ubuntu9.14 arm64 [upgradable from: 2.31-0ubuntu9.12]
N: There are 2 additional versions. Please use the '-a' switch to see them.
```

When trying to upgrade the result was as follow

```bash
$ sudo apt upgrade 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
Get more security updates through Ubuntu Pro with 'esm-apps' enabled:
  libavformat58 libavfilter7 libpython3.9-minimal libswresample3
  libpython3.9-stdlib libzmq5 iperf3 python2.7-minimal libpython2.7 python2.7
  python3.9 libpostproc55 python3.9-minimal libavcodec58 libavutil56
  libswscale5 libopenexr24 libsdl2-2.0-0 libmysofa1 libiperf0
  libpython2.7-minimal libpython2.7-stdlib python3-scipy
Learn more about Ubuntu Pro at https://ubuntu.com/pro
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libc-bin
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 standard LTS security update
Need to get 0 B/501 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,024 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 161696 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libc-bin_2.31-0ubuntu9.14_arm64.deb ...
Unpacking libc-bin (2.31-0ubuntu9.14) over (2.31-0ubuntu9.12) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libc-bin_2.31-0ubuntu9.14_arm64.deb (--unpack):
 unable to stat './usr/lib/locale/C.UTF-8/LC_NUMERIC' (which I was about to install): Bad message
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libc-bin_2.31-0ubuntu9.14_arm64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

**Ubuntu details :**

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

**What I tried ?**

1. Followed a similar issue fix available at [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/989694/how-to-solve-dpkg-error-processing-archive-var-cache-apt-archives-libvlccore9).
2. Tried to `purge` the package and reinstall it. But, received a warning when trying to remove the package.
3. Tried force install
4. Used `--fix-broken` flag with `update` and `upgrade` command