# Breeze has unmet dependencies after trying to upgrade to 18.10 from 18.04

Tags: kubuntu, dependencies, plasma

Yesterday I tried to upgrade my PC with Kubuntu to 18.10. During the installation process there occurred an error because of breeze (probably).

Now I am stuck with 18.04 and can't execute `apt upgrade` or `do-release-upgrade` etc. It always shows the following error message:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
breeze : Depends: breeze-cursor-theme (4:5.12.6-0ubuntu0.1) but 4:5.13.5-0ubuntu2 is to be installed
...
plasma-integration : Depends: breeze (>= 4:5.13) but 4:5.12.6-0-ubuntu0.1 is to be installed
```

Running `apt --fix-broken install` or purging and reinstalling breeze couldn't fix the issue...

Edit - output of `apt-cache policy breeze`:

```
breeze:
  Installed: 4:5.12.6-0ubuntu0.1
  Candidate: 4:5.13.5-0ubuntu2
  Version table:
    4:5.13.5-0ubuntu2 500
      500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic/universe amd64 Packages
 *** 4:5.12.6-0ubuntu0.1 100
      100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: Look at the version numbers: 4:5.12.6 is in Ubuntu 18.04, while 4:5.13.5 is in Ubuntu 18.10. You are trying to add software from the wrong release of Ubuntu, and that usually doesn't work. Check your sources - disable all wrong-version sources.

Comment: I noticed that and also tried to manually specify the version with apt-get but it failed because this would overwrite a file which is also in plasma-look-land-fell... (4:5.12...) and I can neither update nor purge that one because of breeze. I may try however if I can change the source repositories if that is what you mean - do you know the path where they are? Plasma just instantly freezes...

Comment: Sources are in /etc/apt

Comment: Just checked the file and all bionic sources are commented out, only the cosmic ones are enabled

Comment: Edit your question to post the complete output of `apt-cache policy breeze`

Comment: @user535733 indentation might be a bit of because I'm writing this from my phone

Comment: Delete the older version of breeze from your package cache: `sudo apt clean breeze`, Then try `sudo apt update` then `sudo apt upgrade` again. This should make apt download the new version.

Comment: I have also tried apt clean... without any results. BUT I just made multiple tries running apt remove, apt purge and apt-get with specific versions and after handling both packages in one command and reversing the order it seems to have worked. Thank you for the effort - I think apt-cache nudged me in the right direction ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [dpkg error: "trying to overwrite file, which is also in..."](https://askubuntu.com/questions/176121/dpkg-error-trying-to-overwrite-file-which-is-also-in)