# Not possible to install anything on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: 18.04, software-installation, wine, dpkg, dependencies

It's not possible to install anything on my Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. When I run

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

I get:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine32:i386 : Depends: libwine:i386 (= 3.0-1ubuntu1) but it is not installed
 wine64 : Depends: libwine (= 3.0-1ubuntu1) but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

When I run

```
sudo  apt --fix-broken install
```

I get the error-messages after a while:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  fonts-wine libwine libwine:i386
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  fonts-wine libwine libwine:i386
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 10 not upgraded.
15 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/39,9 MB of archives.
After this operation, 375 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 373690 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libwine_3.0-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libwine:amd64 (3.0-1ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libwine_3.0-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/wine/acledit.dll.so', which is also in package wine1.8-amd64 1:1.8.0-0ubuntu1~ubuntu15.10.1~ppa1
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Preparing to unpack .../libwine_3.0-1ubuntu1_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libwine:i386 (3.0-1ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libwine_3.0-1ubuntu1_i386.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/wine/acledit.dll.so', which is also in package wine1.8-i386:i386 1:1.8.0-0ubuntu1~ubuntu15.10.1~ppa1
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Preparing to unpack .../fonts-wine_3.0-1ubuntu1_all.deb ...
Unpacking fonts-wine (3.0-1ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/fonts-wine_3.0-1ubuntu1_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/wine/fonts/coue1255.fon', which is also in package wine1.8 1:1.8.0-0ubuntu1~ubuntu15.10.1~ppa1
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libwine_3.0-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libwine_3.0-1ubuntu1_i386.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/fonts-wine_3.0-1ubuntu1_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

So something about wine....

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: You can try the following, `sudo apt remove --purge wine* libwine* && sudo apt clean && sudo apt update` then reinstall wine completely, this should ususally fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems similar problem as [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/176121/dpkg-error-trying-to-overwrite-file-which-is-also-in). It refers to another package, but the output error is the same `trying to overwrite file, which is also in…`

The solution here is to (force) remove the package that causes the error, directly with `dpkg` . The problematic package is mentioned after the `which is also in <package to be removed>`

In your case `wine1.8-amd64` , `wine1.8-i386` and `wine1.8`

The following commands should do the trick:

```
sudo dpkg -P wine1.8
sudo dpkg -P wine1.8-amd64
sudo dpkg -P wine1.8-i386
```

Then run again

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

and `dpkg` should now be able to configure the packages correctly.

If for some reason above commands won't work, then use the `--force-all` option. **Dangerous option as it can break things**, but it is there for a reason.

```
sudo dpkg -P --force-all wine1.8
sudo dpkg -P --force-all wine1.8-amd64
sudo dpkg -P --force-all wine1.8-i386
```

Also, if you still have any PPA about wine enabled, [please disable it or completely remove it](https://askubuntu.com/a/310/95393).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but when i run: sudo dpkg -P wine1.8
I get: dpkg: dependency problems prevent removal of wine1.8:
 wine1.8-i386:i386 depends on wine1.8:any (= 1:1.8.0-0ubuntu1~ubuntu15.10.1~ppa1).
 wine1.8-amd64 depends on wine1.8:any (= 1:1.8.0-0ubuntu1~ubuntu15.10.1~ppa1).

dpkg: error processing package wine1.8 (--purge):
 dependency problems - not removing
Errors were encountered while processing:
 wine1.8
Do you have any idea on how to deal with/circumvent this

Comment: Try to run the commands in another order. 
1st `sudo dpkg -P wine1.8-amd64` , then `sudo dpkg -P wine1.8-i386`, last `sudo dpkg -P wine1.8`.

Comment: Sorry, but each of the commands returns an error message: sudo dpkg -P wine1.8-amd64, returns
dpkg: dependency problems prevent removal of wine1.8-amd64:
 wine1.8 depends on wine1.8-amd64 (= 1:1.8.0-0ubuntu1~ubuntu15.10.1~ppa1).

dpkg: error processing package wine1.8-amd64 (--purge):
 dependency problems - not removing
Errors were encountered while processing:
 wine1.8-amd64, and similar for the other two

Comment: OK then. I think is time to use the `force` option. Use the same commands but with force option. Dangerous option as it can break things, but it is there for a reason. Example `sudo dpkg -P --force-all wine1.8-amd64`. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked! I did an upgrade and update after I ran a fix command, when everything just worked fine!

Comment: I edited my answer and added the alternative with  `--force-all` commands.