# Error processing archive while trying to upgrade

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, updates, dpkg

The following error occurred while running the command `sudo apt upgrade`:

```
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/wireless-regdb_2018.05.09-0ubuntu1~16.04.1_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/lib/crda/pubkeys/sforshee.key.pub.pem', which is also in package crda 3.18-0ubuntu1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/wireless-regdb_2018.05.09-0ubuntu1~16.04.1_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two ways:

1) Clean way is to remove conflicting package:

```
sudo apt remove crda
sudo apt upgrade
```

2) Unclean way is to force overwriting:

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/wireless-regdb_2018.05.09-0ubuntu1~16.04.1_all.deb
sudo apt upgrade
```

If it helps, upvote https://askubuntu.com/a/176132/486734 and https://askubuntu.com/a/433510/486734, once you have enough reputation.