# nvidia-cuda-dev shows up as unmet dependency, and all nvidia-operations are blocked

Tags: drivers, nvidia, dependencies, cuda

I tried installing Cuda 10.1 according to the instructions on the site. After that, I made a simple C program to test out `nvcc`, and it said I didn't have some `nvidia-cuda` package installed.

I installed it with `apt-get`, and the download completed with one error, that `nvidia-cuda-dev` couldn't be installed.

Now I can't open `nvidia-settings`, because `nvidia-cuda-dev` has an unmet dependency, and I can't remove all nvidia pakcages with `apt purge`, because `nvidia-cuda-dev` has an unmet dependency.

Not sure what to do next, I'll be here a while.

P.S : I've also tried using

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

but it says `nvidia-cuda-dev` is going to be installed, but then says :

```
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/nvidia-cuda-dev_9.1.85-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb (--unpack): trying to overwrite '/usr/include/cublas.h' which is also in package libcublas-dev 10.2.1.243-1
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe) 
Errors were encountered while processing: /var/cache/apt/archives/nvidia-cuda-dev_9.1.85-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb 
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [dpkg error: "trying to overwrite file, which is also in..."](https://askubuntu.com/questions/176121/dpkg-error-trying-to-overwrite-file-which-is-also-in)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what was going on: I had turned my nvidia-settings to use only intel card, I had to go into root to toggle that, and then restart. Then the packages could be uninstalled. I'll post the forum that I read this from.

Answer (score 0):

your package system is broken.

first aid.

```
sudo mv /usr/include/cublas.h $HOME
```

moves file in user home.
2 packages containing the same file.

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a && sudo apt -f install
```

After that, one of the package has to be removed. libcublas-dev 10.2.1.243-1 or nvidia-cuda-dev_9.1.85-3ubuntu1.

Comment: Hello. I tried your instructions, but I am getting the unmet dependency error from the second step for nvidia-cuda-toolkit (which needs nvidia-cuda-dev).
`sudo apt purge libcublas*` seemed to fix it, even though I had already purged the specific library in the error (There were three other libcubla packages).

I have solved this problem, I just hope I haven't caused any other problems in doing so.