# can't install any software

Tags: apt, system-installation

I try to install **sudo apt-get install boinc**
But i try to install another parkket but i can't install any software on the computer it just says: (**sudo apt-get install boinc**)

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 boinc : Depends: boinc-client (>= 7.6.31+dfsg-6ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
         Depends: boinc-manager (>= 7.6.31+dfsg-6ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
 nvidia-cuda-toolkit : Depends: nvidia-cuda-dev (= 7.5.18-0ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

then i run **sudo apt-get -f install** still does not working !

How can we fix the issues??

**Edit 20-02-2020 21:34**
Here is my **sudo apt-get update**

```
hostings@hostings:~$ sudo apt-get update
Get:1 file:/var/cuda-repo-10-2-local-10.2.89-440.33.01  InRelease
Ign:1 file:/var/cuda-repo-10-2-local-10.2.89-440.33.01  InRelease
Get:2 file:/var/cuda-repo-10-2-local-10.2.89-440.33.01  Release [574 B]
Get:2 file:/var/cuda-repo-10-2-local-10.2.89-440.33.01  Release [574 B]
Hit:3 http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                                                                 
Hit:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease                                                                          
Hit:5 http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease                                                                         
Hit:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ethereum/ethereum/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                                                   
Hit:7 http://dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease                                                        
Ign:8 http://webmin.mirror.somersettechsolutions.co.uk/repository sarge InRelease                                           
Hit:10 http://webmin.mirror.somersettechsolutions.co.uk/repository sarge Release                       
Ign:11 http://download.webmin.com/download/repository sarge InRelease                                  
Hit:12 http://download.webmin.com/download/repository sarge Release              
Reading package lists... Done
```

**Edit 21-02-2020 11:03**

I run this command here: 
(**sudo apt-get -f install**)

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  nvidia-cuda-dev
Recommended packages:
  libnvcuvid1
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  nvidia-cuda-dev
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 44 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/201 MB of archives.
After this operation, 467 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 194785 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../nvidia-cuda-dev_7.5.18-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nvidia-cuda-dev (7.5.18-0ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/nvidia-cuda-dev_7.5.18-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/stubs/libcublas.so', which is also in package libcublas-dev 10.2.2.89-1
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/nvidia-cuda-dev_7.5.18-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

Comment: Have you done `sudo apt-get update` yet on this system?  this sometimes happens when you ave outdated information or it can't find the packages it needs available.

Comment: We don't know your release, nor if you've messed up sources by adding a repository for another release (https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=boinc-client)

Comment: Xenial is also very old, I'd consider upgrading right now since the BOINC clients have changed over time.

Comment: Yes i know the old system 16.04.06, will you use this command here? sudo apt-get upgrade

Comment: You need to go down the rabbit-hole and try to install `boinc-client` and `boinc-manager`. That feedback will tell you why they are "not going to be installed." Usually it's some kind of version conflict, but your output will tell the true reason.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [dpkg error: "trying to overwrite file, which is also in..."](https://askubuntu.com/questions/176121/dpkg-error-trying-to-overwrite-file-which-is-also-in)

Answer (score 1):

you could try this:

```
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get -f install
```

then:

```
sudo apt-get install boinc
```