# Vim breaks ubuntu18.04 requesting for vim-common 2:8.0.1453-1ubuntu1.3

Tags: vim

```
Preparing to unpack .../vim-runtime_2%3a8.0.1453-1ubuntu1.3_all.deb ...
Unpacking vim-runtime (2:8.0.1453-1ubuntu1.3) over (2:8.0.1453-1ubuntu1.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/vim-runtime_2%3a8.0.1453-1ubuntu1.3_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/vim/vim80/doc/help.txt', which is also in package vim-tiny 2:8.0.1453-1ubuntu1.3
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/vim-runtime_2%3a8.0.1453-1ubuntu1.3_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

When `sudo dpkg --configure -a` is run

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of vim-tiny:
 vim-tiny depends on vim-common (= 2:8.0.1453-1ubuntu1.3); however:
  Package vim-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package vim-tiny (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of vim:
 vim depends on vim-common (= 2:8.0.1453-1ubuntu1.3); however:
  Package vim-common is not configured yet.
 vim depends on vim-runtime (= 2:8.0.1453-1ubuntu1.3); however:
  Version of vim-runtime on system is 2:8.0.1453-1ubuntu1.1.

dpkg: error processing package vim (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 vim-tiny
 vim
```

I have tried

`sudo apt install -f` || `sudo apt install --fix-broken`

All with no success

Comment: Does this answer your question? [dpkg error: "trying to overwrite file, which is also in..."](https://askubuntu.com/questions/176121/dpkg-error-trying-to-overwrite-file-which-is-also-in)

Comment: @pLumo not exactly but a force overwrite was necessary. I ended up downloading vim run time from https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/18.04/ubuntu-updates-main-amd64/vim-runtime_8.0.1453-1ubuntu1.3_all.deb.html and then installing it with the --force-overwrite flag

Answer (score 0):

I ended up fetching the requested dependency version (2:8.0.1453-1ubuntu1.3) `vim-runtime` manually from https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/18.04/ubuntu-updates-main-amd64/vim-runtime_8.0.1453-1ubuntu1.3_all.deb.html

I then ran,

`sudo dpkg -i vim--runtime_{version}` which returned an overwrite error:

```
Unpacking vim-runtime (2:8.0.1453-1ubuntu1.3) over (2:8.0.1453-1ubuntu1.1) ...
dpkg: warning: overriding problem because --force enabled:
dpkg: warning: trying to overwrite '/usr/share/vim/vim80/doc/help.txt', which is also in package vim-tiny 2:8.0.1453-1ubuntu1.3
dpkg: warning: overriding problem because --force enabled:
dpkg: warning: trying to overwrite '/usr/share/vim/vim80/doc/tags', which is also in package vim-tiny 2:8.0.1453-1ubuntu1.3
Setting up vim-runtime (2:8.0.1453-1ubuntu1.3) ...
```

This was fixed by running : `sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite vim--runtime_{version}`