# Error of broken packages of nvidia-cuda-dev while installing elasticsearch

Tags: nvidia, package-management, cuda, elasticsearch

I am trying to install elasticsearch on my remote machine using the following commands ..

```
wget -qO - https://artifacts.elastic.co/GPG-KEY-elasticsearch | sudo apt-key add -

sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https

echo "deb https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/7.x/apt stable main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elastic-7.x.list

sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install elasticsearch
```

While installing, I am getting the following error

**The following packages have unmet dependencies:
nvidia-cuda-toolkit : Depends: nvidia-cuda-dev (= 9.1.85-3ubuntu1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).**

I tried with the solutions like

```
apt --fix-broken install
```

for which i am getting the error

```
apt --fix-broken install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libllvm9
Use 'apt autoremove' to remove it.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  nvidia-cuda-dev
Recommended packages:
  libnvcuvid1
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  nvidia-cuda-dev
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 38 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/263 MB of archives.
After this operation, 734 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 175495 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../nvidia-cuda-dev_9.1.85-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nvidia-cuda-dev (9.1.85-3ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/nvidia-cuda-dev_9.1.85-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/include/cublas.h', which is also in package libcublas-dev 10.2.1.243-1
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
**Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/nvidia-cuda-dev_9.1.85-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)**
```

I also tried

```
sudo apt -f install
```

for which i got the error

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libllvm9
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  nvidia-cuda-dev
Recommended packages:
  libnvcuvid1
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  nvidia-cuda-dev
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 38 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/263 MB of archives.
After this operation, 734 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 175495 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../nvidia-cuda-dev_9.1.85-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nvidia-cuda-dev (9.1.85-3ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/nvidia-cuda-dev_9.1.85-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/include/cublas.h', which is also in package libcublas-dev 10.2.1.243-1
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
**Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/nvidia-cuda-dev_9.1.85-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)**
```

Please suggest how to pass this

Comment: Does this answer your question? [dpkg error: "trying to overwrite file, which is also in..."](https://askubuntu.com/questions/176121/dpkg-error-trying-to-overwrite-file-which-is-also-in)

Answer (score 0):

Try running this command:

```
sudo apt install cuda-toolkit-9-1
```

It works for me.