# Error encountered with /var/cache/apt/archives/base-files_10.1ubuntu2.2_amd64.deb trying to update packages

Tags: updates

I tried multiple things to get this to work, but it's not working:

I'm running `sudo apt-get upgrade` and get the following error:

```
Preparing to unpack .../base-files_10.1ubuntu2.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking base-files (10.1ubuntu2.2) over (9.4ubuntu4.13) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/base-files_10.1ubuntu2.2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/etc/default/motd-news', which is also in package motd-news-config 9.4ubuntu4.13
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/base-files_10.1ubuntu2.2_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [dpkg error: "trying to overwrite file, which is also in..."](https://askubuntu.com/questions/176121/dpkg-error-trying-to-overwrite-file-which-is-also-in)

Comment: Not really.  When I try to remove the conflicting package I get:  root@lemp-512mb-nyc3-01:~# sudo dpkg -P motd-news-config
dpkg: dependency problems prevent removal of motd-news-config:
 ubuntu-server depends on motd-news-config.

dpkg: error processing package motd-news-config (--purge):
 dependency problems - not removing
Errors were encountered while processing:
 motd-news-config

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Then force installation of base-files by

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-all /var/cache/apt/archives/base-files_10.1ubuntu2.2_amd64.deb
```

and resume upgrade by

```
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Comment: Thank you!!!  That was driving me nuts.  I wanted to stay up to date, but couldn't find the solution anywhere.

Comment: the 2nd command should be `sudo apt-get upgrade`. OP is not looking for distribution upgrade