# dpkg: error processing archive mesa/nvidia/vulkan

Tags: package-management, dependencies

I installed a new nvidia driver on Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS AMD64 and now try to install vulkan packages. I seem to get conflicting package errors:

```
dpkg: error processing archive /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-76p1rq/0-libglx-dev_1.3.2-1~oibaf~b_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/include/GL/glx.h', which is also in package mesa-common-dev:amd64 20.0.8-0ubuntu1~18.04.1
Preparing to unpack .../1-libgl-dev_1.3.2-1~oibaf~b_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libgl-dev:amd64 (1.3.2-1~oibaf~b) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-76p1rq/1-libgl-dev_1.3.2-1~oibaf~b_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/include/GL/gl.h', which is also in package mesa-common-dev:amd64 20.0.8-0ubuntu1~18.04.1
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Preparing to unpack .../2-libglx-dev_1.3.2-1~oibaf~b_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libglx-dev:i386 (1.3.2-1~oibaf~b) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-76p1rq/2-libglx-dev_1.3.2-1~oibaf~b_i386.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/include/GL/glx.h', which is also in package mesa-common-dev:amd64 20.0.8-0ubuntu1~18.04.1
Preparing to unpack .../3-libgl-dev_1.3.2-1~oibaf~b_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libgl-dev:i386 (1.3.2-1~oibaf~b) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-76p1rq/3-libgl-dev_1.3.2-1~oibaf~b_i386.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/include/GL/gl.h', which is also in package mesa-common-dev:amd64 20.0.8-0ubuntu1~18.04.1
```

I tried sudo apt --fix-broken install but it didn't help.

Can anyone help?

Regards

Comment: Does this answer your question? [dpkg error: "trying to overwrite file, which is also in..."](https://askubuntu.com/questions/176121/dpkg-error-trying-to-overwrite-file-which-is-also-in)

Comment: Not really because vulkaninfo insisted on libgl-dev. I now used sudo apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-overwrite" install --fix-broken although I cannot rule out it causes problems in the future.