# Package depends on higher version of itself (nvidia-kernel-common)

Tags: 18.04, nvidia, package-management, cuda

I'm getting an error notification on startup about broken packages. My computer is very slow. When I follow the recommendation of running the Package Manager or running `apt upgrade`, I get:

```
nvidia-kernel-common-465 : Depends: nvidia-kernel-common-470 but it is not installed
```

I tried:

```
$ sudo apt --fix-broken install
...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/nvidia-kernel-common-470_470.57.02-1pop0~1627044105~18.04~f9815ed~dev_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/lib/systemd/system/nvidia-hibernate.service', which is also in package nvidia-driver-465 465.31-1pop0~1623777959~18.04~a3ca7f3~dev
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/nvidia-kernel-common-470_470.57.02-1pop0~1627044105~18.04~f9815ed~dev_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Here are my current devices:

```
$ ubuntu-drivers devices
WARNING:root:_pkg_get_support nvidia-driver-390: package has invalid Support Legacyheader, cannot determine support level
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.1/0000:0a:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd00001D01sv00001462sd00008C98bc03sc00i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
model    : GP108 [GeForce GT 1030]
manual_install: True
driver   : nvidia-driver-470-server - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-390 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-418-server - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-460-server - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-450-server - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-470 - third-party non-free recommended
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin

== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.3/0000:02:00.2/0000:03:05.0/0000:07:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v00008086d00002526sv00008086sd00000014bc02sc80i00
vendor   : Intel Corporation
manual_install: True
driver   : backport-iwlwifi-dkms - distro free
```

Comment: `sudo dpkg -P nvidia-driver-465`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [dpkg error: "trying to overwrite file, which is also in..."](https://askubuntu.com/questions/176121/dpkg-error-trying-to-overwrite-file-which-is-also-in)

Answer (score 5):

Following [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/176121/dpkg-error-trying-to-overwrite-file-which-is-also-in) posted by @nobody, I resolved running:

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/nvidia-driver-470_470.57.02-0ubuntu0.20.04.1_amd64.deb
sudo apt -f install
```

Comment: remove the other nvidia package I wrote in my first comment. you will probably run in the same error again.