# sudo apt-get problems (Only sudo apt-get update is accessible)

Tags: package-management, upgrade, dependencies

I can only do `sudo apt-get update`, anything else gives me errors.

Output of sudo apt-get update:

```
Hit:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:2 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [114 kB]
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [114 kB]
Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [101 kB]
Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages [1,260 kB]
Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main i386 Packages [545 kB]
Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [283 kB]
Get:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 Packages [865 kB]
Get:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [361 kB]
Get:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages [24.7 kB]
Get:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/multiverse i386 Packages [8,252 B]
Get:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [944 B]
Get:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [29.1 kB]
Get:15 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [62.4 kB]
Get:16 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [2,468 B]
Get:17 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [10.4 kB]
Fetched 3,781 kB in 9s (414 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
```

OS: Ubuntu 20.04.3 - Focal
I've tried everything to install these dependencies to no avail.

Output of sudo apt install -f:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  gir1.2-playerctl-1.0 libplayerctl-1.0-0
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  gir1.2-playerctl-2.0
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  gir1.2-playerctl-2.0
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/4,224 B of archives.
After this operation, 24.6 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libplayerctl2:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libplayerctl-1.0-0:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
(Reading database ... 282830 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../gir1.2-playerctl-2.0_2.0.2-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gir1.2-playerctl-2.0:amd64 (2.0.2-1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/gir1.2-playerctl-2.0_2.0.2-1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/girepository-1.0/Playerctl-2.0.typelib', which is also in package gir1.2-playerctl-1.0:amd64 2.0.2-1ubuntu1~ppa2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/gir1.2-playerctl-2.0_2.0.2-1_amd64.deb
```

Output of sudo apt-get upgrade :

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libplayerctl-dev : Depends: gir1.2-playerctl-2.0 (= 2.0.2-1) but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Output of sudo apt --fix-broken install :

```
roolz@roolz:~$ sudo apt --fix-broken install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  gir1.2-playerctl-1.0 libplayerctl-1.0-0
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  gir1.2-playerctl-2.0
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  gir1.2-playerctl-2.0
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/4,224 B of archives.
After this operation, 24.6 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libplayerctl2:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libplayerctl-1.0-0:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
(Reading database ... 282830 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../gir1.2-playerctl-2.0_2.0.2-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gir1.2-playerctl-2.0:amd64 (2.0.2-1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/gir1.2-playerctl-2.0_2.0.2-1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/girepository-1.0/Playerctl-2.0.typelib', which is also in package gir1.2-playerctl-1.0:amd64 2.0.2-1ubuntu1~ppa2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/gir1.2-playerctl-2.0_2.0.2-1_amd64.deb
```

Comment: Have you tried the command suggested in the error message (or `sudo apt instal -f` which is the same)? If so, what were the results? Please edit the question to add relevant information and also Ubuntu release/version.

Comment: @Nmath fixed, sorry first time posting on here didn't know proper format.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Edited.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [dpkg error: "trying to overwrite file, which is also in..."](https://askubuntu.com/questions/176121/dpkg-error-trying-to-overwrite-file-which-is-also-in)

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems clearly stated in the output:

```
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/gir1.2-playerctl-2.0_2.0.2-1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/girepository-1.0/Playerctl-2.0.typelib', which is also in package gir1.2-playerctl-1.0:amd64 2.0.2-1ubuntu1~ppa2
```

Let's break that down a bit:

```
dpkg: error processing archive X (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite Y, which is also in package Z

X = /var/cache/apt/archives/gir1.2-playerctl-2.0_2.0.2-1_amd64.deb
Y = '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/girepository-1.0/Playerctl-2.0.typelib'
Z = gir1.2-playerctl-1.0:amd64 2.0.2-1ubuntu1~ppa2
```

Both X and Z are trying to provide file Y. In this case, Uninstall package Z to resolve the conflict.

`sudo apt remove gir1.2-playerctl-1.0:amd64`

Comment: `roolz@roolz:/var/cache/apt/archives$ sudo apt remove gir1.2-playerctl-1.0:amd64 2.0.2-1ubuntu1-ppa2
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package 2.0.2-1ubuntu1-ppa2
E: Couldn't find any package by glob '2.0.2-1ubuntu1-ppa2'
`   This is was the output to the command.

Comment: There was a typo in my command. Fixed now; try again. Don't blindly copy a command that you don't fully understand -- that's an easy path to break your system.