# A snap install attempt of selenium webdriver's or Chromium-chromedriver has ruined my package management

Tags: apt, package-management, snap

```
root@landicho:~# apt install --fix-broken
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  chromium-browser
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  chromium-browser
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/48.3 kB of archives.
After this operation, 164 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 295137 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../chromium-browser_1%3a85.0.4183.83-0ubuntu0.20.04.2_amd64.deb ...
=> Installing the chromium snap
==> Checking connectivity with the snap store
==> Installing the chromium snap
error: snap "chromium" has "install-snap" change in progress
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/chromium-browser_1%3a85.0.4183.83-0ubuntu0.20.04.2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 new chromium-browser package pre-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/chromium-browser_1%3a85.0.4183.83-0ubuntu0.20.04.2_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

---snip---
I try all sorts of ways to clean this up, and they all fail.  I have never been this stuck in some 15 years of using Ubuntu.  I just want to eliminate the chromium and webdriver stuff to get my system normal again.

Comment: I see `snap "chromium" has "install-snap" change in progress` so have you waited for that to complete?   I have found snap updates (changes) can take awhile; esp. if the snap is open and it waits for the closure...

Comment: Does this answer your question [dpkg error: "trying to overwrite file, which is also in..."](https://askubuntu.com/questions/176121/dpkg-error-trying-to-overwrite-file-which-is-also-in)

Comment: "*I try all sorts of ways to clean this up, and they all fail*" Since we don't know what you have tried, it seems likely that we will waste a lot of effort telling you to try the same ways again. Rather that waste their effort, many volunteers here who might be able to help won't bother and will move on to another question. You can get better and faster help if your question details what you tried and why each failed.