# I am trying to update ubuntu but is not working

Tags: 20.04, updates, python

I have this problem and I don t know what to do, I have tried  a couple of things but I am stuck. Can you help me please.
[image]

[image]

Output of `sudo apt update; sudo apt -f install`:

```
$ sudo apt update; sudo apt -f install
Hit:1 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
Hit:3 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease              
Hit:4 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                      
Hit:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease     
Hit:6 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease            
Hit:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/lutris-team/lutris/ubuntu focal InRelease       
Get:8 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu bionic InRelease [6,263 B]      
Hit:9 http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/strycore/Debian_10 ./ InRelease
Hit:10 https://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable InRelease                       
Hit:11 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                 
Hit:12 https://ocean.surfshark.com/debian stretch InRelease                    
Hit:13 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/20.04/mssql-server-2019 focal InRelease
Hit:14 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/ms-teams stable InRelease
Hit:15 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu focal InRelease 
Get:16 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages [939 kB]
Get:17 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu bionic/main i386 Packages [975 kB]
Fetched 1,920 kB in 2s (877 kB/s)                     
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
59 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  python3-catkin
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  python3-catkin-pkg-modules
The following NEW packages will be installed
  python3-catkin-pkg-modules
0 to upgrade, 1 to newly install, 0 to remove and 59 not to upgrade.
500 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/42.4 kB of archives.
After this operation, 254 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 399552 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../python3-catkin-pkg-modules_0.4.24-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking python3-catkin-pkg-modules (0.4.24-1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/python3-catkin-pkg-module
s_0.4.24-1_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/catkin_pkg/__init__.py', wh
ich is also in package python3-catkin-pkg 0.4.16-1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/python3-catkin-pkg-modules_0.4.24-1_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Please [edit] to post the output of `sudo apt update; sudo apt -f install`

Comment: I have tried and I have updated the post

Comment: Please don't add screenshots of terminal text .. they are difficult to read and search in. Instead copy/paste the text into OP and format it properly.

Comment: ok I edit it. Thanks.

Comment: What commands did you run to get here? The last command in your screenshot needed to have `sudo`... but I,m guessing youre not at that point any longer?

Comment: I run it with sudo as well and is the same problem

Comment: The other error in that image `could not lock...` means e.g. you have apt loaded in another terminal somewhere. Do you have any `apt install` instances waiting on `Y/n` or similar? This will block Apt in all the other terminals you have loaded. Somewhere you have another process blocking `dpkg`

Comment: run the command `dpkg-query -l '*' ` and look at the list output. Each line will start with a 2-letter descriptor. Which descriptors are you seeing most on your list.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [dpkg error: "trying to overwrite file, which is also in..."](https://askubuntu.com/questions/176121/dpkg-error-trying-to-overwrite-file-which-is-also-in).

Answer (score 1):

The specific problem you are encountering is indeed a clear duplicate of [dpkg error: "trying to overwrite file, which is also in..."](https://askubuntu.com/questions/176121), but there's an underlying problem: Your system has lots of newer software from several non-Ubuntu sources bolted onto an older LTS. We call this a "Frankensystem".

- LTS releases are stable and secure for five years *if you don't change the software*.
- Frankensystems tend to be unstable, and the various sources often provide packages that *conflict* with each other...which is exactly the problem you have.
- Generally, most folks who want newer software will get the best experience if they use a newer release of Ubuntu --or-- install the newer software using a snap instead of a deb.